# Distinct elements in django model

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I'm a Django newbie and I wonder if there is a more efficient way (at a database level) of doing the following.

I have the model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    item=models.IntegerField()
    another_item=models.IntegerField()
```

And want to get an iterable of all the distinct values of "item".

This is what I have so far:

```
distinct=set([row.item for row in Foo.objects.all()])
```

This is easy to understand. But if I'm understanding how Django works then the SQL query is not very efficient because it is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM DB
```

when I only need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item FROM DB
```

Any way of doing this more efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `distinct` clause in combination with the `values` or `values_list` clauses.

[Doc starts here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct). `distinct`, `values` and `values_list` are all in there.

So you could do:

```
Foo.objects.values_list('item', flat=True)
```

And that would return a list of item - matching your `SELECT DISTINCT item FROM DB` query.

Comment: This seems to be working. 
Do you know of a way of checking the query that's being generated by a django expression?

Comment: Ok... It's been asked already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/show-the-sql-django-is-running

Comment: Great.. I checked and you are 100% correct. Thank you

Foo.objects.all().values_list('item', flat=True).distinct()

I'm starting to love Django as much as I love Python

Comment: You don't need the `.all()` in there. Just `Foo.objects.values_list('item', flat=True)`

Comment: to see the sql: just append `.query.as_sql()` to any queryset