# How to log all sql queries in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, logging, django-database

How can I log all SQL queries that my django application performed?

I want to log everything, including SQLs from admin site. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/show-the-sql-django-is-running) and [a FAQ answer](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) but I still can't figure out where should I put

```
from django.db import connection
connection.queries
```

to log everything to one file?

So my question is - what should I do to have a file (say all-sql.log) where all SQL statements are logged?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-to-show-the-sql-django-is-running

Comment: I got "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured." error when using the code "from django.db import connection
print(connection.queries)" in "settings.py" for "Django==3.1.7".

Comment: Also have a look at: [Log SQL queries even if DEBUG=False](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58396629)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maybe check out https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar

It'll let you see all the queries generated by a given page.  As well as stacktraces of where they occur etc.

EDIT: to log all SQL queries to a file etc, then you will want to create some middleware.  Middleware gets run on every request.  There are several Django snippets out there for this sort of thing:

- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/290/
- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/264/

Those are concerned with printing to the terminal, but it wouldn't be hard to adapt them to use python's logging library.

Comment: There's built-in logging / tracing capability without debugging: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556139/get-sql-query-count-during-a-django-shell-session#

Answer (score 255):

Merge the following snippet with the `LOGGING` field in your `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        }
    }
}
```

Tweaked from @acardenas89 answer

Comment: you may need to add the following to the `handlers` section in case you get _Unable to add handler 'console': 'console'_ error:  `'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'stream': sys.stderr,
        },`

Comment: I also needed `'version': 1,` in the `LOGGING` dict.

Comment: Please note that [DEBUG must be TRUE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#django-db-backends) for logs to actually be logged. Regardless of logging settings.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing to in django test runner ignores settings and overrides `DEBUG` to `False`, so in test you must `@override_settings(DEBUG=True)`

Comment: I would also add `'propagate': False` after the `'handlers': ['console'],` line, in case you have a root logger enabled and don't know why this prints twice. Took me a bit to realize.

Comment: so complicated just for such basic and common thing

Answer (score 58):

Add the following bold statements in settings.py

```
if DEBUG:
    import logging
    l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
    l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },'django.db.backends.sqlite3': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    }
}
```

[Resource/Credit](http://dabapps.com/blog/logging-sql-queries-django-13/)

Comment: You don't need both the `if` statement at the top and the `LOGGING` changes. The `if` statement is for if you want to add logging whilst e.g. in the shell, to turn it on immediately - all you need in settings.py is the `LOGGING` changes - and you might well want `django.db.backends`, not the sqlite3 specific one.

Comment: I don't see any queries on the console running django 1.9. `DEBUG = True`.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 This is a really old comment, very possibly Django 1.9 does not support this solution the same.

Comment: In Django 1.9, the `DEBUG` setting is forced to be False when running tests.  A workaround is to re-enable it in the test

Answer (score 29):

To log SQL queries during testing, you need two things:

1. `django.db.backends` logger enabled and
2. `@override_settings(DEBUG=True)` [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings).

Test runner will [set DEBUG=False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-debug-mode) by default, ignoring what you may have set in DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

The minimum settings:

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#logging
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
    }
}
```

The example test case:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings


class UserTests(TestCase):

    # To log queries in tests you need to manually override DEBUG setting
    # because testing sets DEBUG=False by default

    @override_settings(DEBUG=True)
    def test_create_user(self):
        User.objects.create()
```

Answer (score 16):

Django 1.3 logs all SQL statements to **django.db.backends** logger:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/logging/#django-db-backends

Answer (score 3):

You only need:

```
@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
```

if you already have SQL debug statements being printed in `runserver`.

Add the decorator to your `class TestA(TestCase)` or `test_function`:

```
@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
class TestA(TestCase):
...

    @override_settings(DEBUG=True)
    def test_function(self):
    ...
```

Credits to @Janusz Skonieczny's answer!

Answer (score 3):

In modern Django we got [native way to hook and instrument sql queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/instrumentation/) without need to install extra dependencies. The OP asked for all queries, but this also can be of a high situational use.

```py
import time

class QueryLogger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queries = []

    def __call__(self, execute, sql, params, many, context):
        current_query = {"sql": sql, "params": params, "many": many}
        start = time.monotonic()
        try:
            result = execute(sql, params, many, context)
        except Exception as e:
            current_query["status"] = "error"
            current_query["exception"] = e
            raise
        else:
            current_query["status"] = "ok"
            return result
        finally:
            duration = time.monotonic() - start
            current_query["duration"] = duration
            self.queries.append(current_query)
(...)

# say, in Django Shell we would like to see 
# whether .exists() is faster than .count() 
# and what raw SQL it actually runs

import pprint
from django.db import connection
    
ql = QueryLogger()
with connection.execute_wrapper(ql):
    Book.objects.filter(author="Uncle Bob").exists()
    Book.objects.filter(author="Uncle Bob").count()

pprint.pprint(ql.queries)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this toggle-able by a setting, do something like the following in settings.py:

```
if LOG_DB_QUERIES:
    LOGGING["handlers"]["console"] = {
        "level": "DEBUG", "class": "logging.StreamHandler"
    }
    LOGGING["loggers"]["django.db.backends"] =  {
        "level": "DEBUG", "handlers": ["console"]
    }
```

Also, please note that this will only work if you have `DEBUG = True` in settings.py.

Thanks to [@Gian Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161527/2800876) for the logging config that makes this work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to log **all SQL queries** in Django to a file.

But, I know how to use the code below to get **the part of the SQL queries** in **Django Admin**. *You can also see [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-to-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running/74904301#74904301) explaining how to get **the part of the SQL queries** in **Django View**:

```py
from django.db import connection
connection.queries
```

For example, you can use **`connection.queries`** in **overridden `save_model()`** in **`Person` admin** to get **the SQL queries** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from .models import Person
from django.db import connection

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Here
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        for query in connection.queries: # Here
            print(query)
```

Then, if you change a person as shown below:

[image]

**The SQL queries** are printed on console as shown below:

```
{'sql': 'SELECT "django_session"."session_key", "django_session"."session_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_session" WHERE ("django_session"."expire_date" > \'2022-12-24T06:47:45.799803+00:00\'::timestamptz AND "django_session"."session_key" = \'7spdc2c5h3g2v5hjc898eqphf11g9eck\') LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.000'}
{'sql': 'SELECT "account_customuser"."id", "account_customuser"."password", "account_customuser"."last_login", "account_customuser"."is_superuser", "account_customuser"."first_name", "account_customuser"."last_name", "account_customuser"."is_staff", "account_customuser"."is_active", "account_customuser"."date_joined", "account_customuser"."email", "account_customuser"."phone", "account_customuser"."my_order" FROM "account_customuser" WHERE "account_customuser"."id" = 1 LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.000'}
{'sql': 'SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" FROM "store_person" WHERE "store_person"."id" = 191 LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.000'}
{'sql': 'UPDATE "store_person" SET "name" = \'David\' WHERE "store_person"."id" = 191', 'time': '0.000'}
[24/Dec/2022 15:47:45] "POST /admin/store/person/191/change/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[24/Dec/2022 15:47:46] "GET /admin/store/person/ HTTP/1.1" 200 22584
[24/Dec/2022 15:47:46] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3195
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this in a middleware package. The middleware sits between the webserver/django core and all your views. It can do preprocessing before the request, and postprocessing after the request completed. For example, save the queries to a file.