# how to subquery in queryset in django?

Tags: python, django

how can i have a subquery in django's queryset? for example if i have:

```
select name, age from person, employee where person.id = employee.id and
employee.id in (select id from employee where employee.company = 'Private')
```

this is what i have done yet.

```
Person.objects.value('name', 'age')
Employee.objects.filter(company='Private')
```

but it not working because it returns two output...

Comment: Your example is not very good. You don't need a subquery for this: `select name, age from person, employee where person.id = employee.id and employee.company = 'Private'`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
ids = Employee.objects.filter(company='Private').values_list('id', flat=True)
Person.objects.filter(id__in=ids).values('name', 'age')
```

Comment: `values_list` returns a `ValuesQuerySet` and those two lines will actually translate into a single query with a subquery.

Comment: This will in fact generate **only one** query, meaning the answer is correct. Additionally, 1. `.values('id')` also works just the same and 2. the use of the `pk` field instead is recommended.

Comment: I think the behaviour of `values_list` depends on django version. This was asked 7 years ago, and I guess some pre-py3-compatible version of django returns `list`, while the later versions return `ValuesQuerySet` and thus constructing subquery.

Comment: @Antoine Actually, **this is a subquery**, And  `.values_list()` **returns a queryset!**  If you don't believe me, try [logging the sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375784/log-all-sql-queries) for this answer.

Comment: I feel obligated to upvote this since 12 people clearly don't know how querysets work.

Comment: Indeed, I don't know what made me think and say that... Maybe at the time the repr of a ValuesListQuerySet looked like a list and/or it did not translate into a subquery back in 2016 but I have no evidence to defend myself.

Answer (score 73):

as mentioned by  ypercube your use case doesn't require subquery.

but anyway since many people land into this page to learn how to do sub-query here is how its done.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery

employee_query = Employee.objects.filter(company='Private').only('id').all()
Person.objects.value('name', 'age').filter(id__in=Subquery(employee_query))
```

Source:
http://mattrobenolt.com/the-django-orm-and-subqueries/

Comment: Mentioned on docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in " can also use a queryset to dynamically evaluate the list of values instead of providing a list of literal values:" and "This queryset will be evaluated as subselect statement".

Comment: In django 3.2 .only('id') is .values_list('id', flat=True)

Answer (score 18):

The correct answer on your question is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

As an example:

```
>>> from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
>>> newest = Comment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')
>>> Post.objects.annotate(newest_commenter_email=Subquery(newest.values('email')[:1]))
```

Answer (score 12):

You can create subqueries in Django by using an [unevaluated queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#in) to filter your main queryset. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
employee_query = Employee.objects.filter(company='Private')
people = Person.objects.filter(employee__in=employee_query)
```

I'm assuming that you have a reverse relationship from `Person` to `Employee` named `employee`. I found it helpful to look at the SQL query generated by a queryset when I was trying to understand how the filters work.

```
print people.query
```

As others have said, you don't really need a subquery for your example. You could just join to the employee table:

```
people2 = Person.objects.filter(employee__company='Private')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hero_qs = Hero.objects.filter(category=OuterRef("pk")).order_by("-benevolence_factor")
Category.objects.all().annotate(most_benevolent_hero=Subquery(hero_qs.values('name')[:1]))
```

the generated sql

```
SELECT "entities_category"."id",
       "entities_category"."name",
  (SELECT U0."name"
   FROM "entities_hero" U0
   WHERE U0."category_id" = ("entities_category"."id")
   ORDER BY U0."benevolence_factor" DESC
   LIMIT 1) AS "most_benevolent_hero"
FROM "entities_category"
```

For more details, see [this article](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/subquery.html).

Comment: This should be a comment not an aswer

Answer (score 0):

Take good care with `only`if your subqueries don't select the primary key.

Example:

```py
class Customer:
    pass

class Order:
    customer: Customer
    pass

class OrderItem:
    order: Order
    is_recalled: bool
```

- Customer has Orders
- Order has OrderItems

Now we are trying to find all customers with at least one recalled order-item.(1)

**This will not work properly**

```py
order_ids = OrderItem.objects \
    .filter(is_recalled=True) \
    .only("order_id")

customer_ids = OrderItem.objects \
    .filter(id__in=order_ids) \
    .only('customer_id')


# BROKEN! BROKEN
customers = Customer.objects.filter(id__in=customer_ids)
```

The code above looks very fine, but it produces the following query:

```sql
select * from customer where id in (
    select id  -- should be customer_id
    from orders 
    where id in (
        select id -- should be order_id
        from order_items 
        where is_recalled = true))
```

Instead one should use `select`

```py
order_ids = OrderItem.objects \
    .filter(is_recalled=True) \
    .select("order_id")

customer_ids = OrderItem.objects \
    .filter(id__in=order_ids) \
    .select('customer_id')


customers = Customer.objects.filter(id__in=customer_ids)
```

(1) Note: in a real case we might consider 'WHERE EXISTS'