# Get SQL query count during a Django shell session

Tags: python, sql, django, shell

Is there a way to print the number of raw SQL queries performed by the Django ORM during a Django shell session?

This sort of information is already provided by the Django debug toolbar (e.g, `5 QUERIES in 5.83MS` but it's not obvious how to get it from the shell.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can use `connection.queries`:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DEBUG = True
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> Model.objects.count()
>>> print(len(connection.queries))
1
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work with Django 1.5, query count stays at 0

Comment: Tried this method using Django 1.11 and it worked perfectly fine!

Comment: One of my go-to's. Also useful with this: `django.db.reset_queries` to reset that count.

Comment: Note, this stops counting at 9000.  See `BaseDatabaseWrapper.queries_limit`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, even in Django 1.11. I had to use Tim Richardson's answer to get the connection with the actual queries.

Comment: Recently was linked to me by a friend after I'd started going this way: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/instrumentation/

Answer (score 26):

This is a slight improvement on the accepted answer. create a python file named extra_imports.py in some app (Eg `some_app`)

extra_imports.py

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.DEBUG = True
from django.db import connection, reset_queries


def num_queries(reset=True):
    print(len(connection.queries))
    if reset:
        reset_queries()
```

Now, If you are using shell_plus from django_extension (btw check it out if you are not using it), add following line to settings.py

```
SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS = [('some_app.extra_imports', '*')]
```

If you are using django shell, run this inside shell

```
exec(open('some_app/extra_imports.py').read()) # python3
execfile('some_app/extra_imports.py').read()) # pyhton2
```

Or you can just paste the contents of `extra_import.py` into the shell

Now,

```
In [1]: User.objects.all()
In [2]: num_queries()
1

In [3]: User.objects.filter(company=Company.objects.first()).all()
In [4]: num_queries()
2
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have database routing and multiple connections, it's a bit trickier to count your database hits because `connection.queries`
considers only the default connection, as far as I can tell.

To include all connections:

```
from django.db import connections,connection,reset_queries
from django.conf import settings
settings.DEBUG = True
...
def query_count_all()->int:
    query_total = 0
    for c in connections.all():
        query_total += len(c.queries)
    return query_total
```

or more concisely:

```
def query_count_all()->int:
   return sum(len(c.queries) for c in connections.all())
```

`reset_queries()` already handles multiple connections