# Django mptt get_cached_trees() hits database

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I am using `get_cached_trees()` method from [django mptt library](https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/utilities.html#get-cached-trees)

As in the docs:

> Takes a list/queryset of model objects in MPTT left (depth-first) order and caches the children and parent on each node. This allows up and down traversal through the tree without the need for further queries.

I am tracking db queries like this:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DEBUG = True
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> Model.objects.count()
>>> # python 3 uses print()
>>> print(len(connection.queries))
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19556140/7127824).

Then I do

```
MyModel.objects.count()
print(len(connection.queries)) # 1
```

Then

```
first_object = MyModel.objects.first()
root_object = first_object.get_root()
print(len(connection.queries)) # 3
```

Then

```
cache = root_object.get_cached_trees()  
print(len(connection.queries)) # 4
```

Then

```
cache[0].get_descendants()
print(len(connection.queries)) # 5
```

Why at the last step it gives me 5? It was supposed not to make a query to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have used `get_children()`, it does not hit DB any extra time.

```
cache[0].get_children()
print(len(connection.queries)) # 4
```

In general, attributes that are cached: `children` and `parent`