# Prefetch related extracted database rows?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using this query with DRF:

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
        show = Show.objects.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'posttitleimage_set',
                queryset=PostTitleImage.objects.filter(post__is_published=True),
            )
        ).exclude(publication__isnull=False)[:5]
```

This should, however, only fetch 5 `shows` from the DB. Also, I'll never run into the case that I will need all `posttitleimages` for one show. I only ever want the latest `posttitleimage` for one show.

```
class ShowIndexSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    last_title_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Show
        fields = (
            ....
            'last_title_image',
        )

    def get_last_title_image(self, obj):
        last_published_image = obj.posttitleimage_set.all()[: 1]
        return ShallowPostTitleImageSerializer(last_published_image, many=True).data
```

While my code manages to reduce the number of queries from 10 to only 4, I am now concerned about the number of rows this will query from the DB. Especially once the DB grows. Also, this seems to be a bit of a hacky solution to just get the latest `posttitleimage` from the DB. Are there some obvious flaws with this implementation. How could this be improved? I'd be super happy about suggestions.

---

**EDIT:**

```
class ShallowPostTitleImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostTitleImage
        fields = (
            'uuid',
            'image',
            'show',
        )
```

Two versions of the get_last_title_image function for the Method field:

**First (causes 9 queries)**:

```
def get_last_title_image(self, obj):
    published_image = obj.posttitleimage_set.first()
    return ShallowPostTitleImageSerializer(published_image).data
```

**Second (causes only 4 queries):**

```
def get_last_title_image(self, obj):
    published_images = obj.posttitleimage_set.all()
    if published_images:
        return ShallowPostTitleImageSerializer(published_images[len(published_images) - 1]).data
    return None
```

Comment: The results of the prefetch are cached to each object in the queryset using 2 queries. Calling `.all()` or `.first()` on the `posttitleimage_set` shouldn't cause any extra queries. What does your `ShallowPostTitleImageSerializer` look like?

Comment: Thats what I thought as will. But using .first() definitely causes 4 more queries. I will update my question with the serializer.

Comment: I also included the two version of the functions to test the number of queries. I profile the requests using Silk

Comment: Interesting, `.first()` definitely causes extra queries but my tests in the shell using `.all()` and the [`num_queries()` function from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593944/8741781) results in 2 queries.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I maybe should have written that the actual code is a bit more complex.Only some of the 9 or 4 queries result from the given code. The problem is, that this fetches a list of shows so every query multiplies by the number of shows fetched. This is a bit problematic for me.

Comment: regarding the `.first()` making an extra query, I ran into that same problem recently and checked [its implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L672): basically if the queryset isn't already ordered when you call `.first()`  it will call `.order_by('pk')` making that xtra query, if you order the prefetched queryset that extra call should go away.