# Get the SQL statement made by a .exists() query in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

Is it possible to print the SQL made by an queryset.exists() statement in Django?

Comment: try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/show-the-sql-django-is-running

Comment: Or better yet, use this: https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar
Once installed it will show all querys used in a request

Answer (score -5):

Usually yes you can print SQL `QuerySet`s generate however since `exists()` does not return a `QuerySet` but returns a simple boolean, it is more difficult.

Perhaps the easiest way is not to print SQL query for just `exists()` but for all queries in the view. You can follow other SO question on how to do that ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375784/log-all-sql-queries)) or you can use [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar).

---

If you are also interesting in printing queries `QuerySet` generates, you can print a complete SQL query using:

```
print(Model.objects.filter(...).exists().query)
```

That will print a complete query.

If your intention however is to be able to copy-paste the query and execute it directly, it might not always work. For example printing the query does not always produce correct syntax such as with dates. There however is another useful method in Django `Query` objects (which is `QuerySet.query` is instance of) - [`sql_with_params()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L216). That returns your parameterized query with the parameters themselves. For example:

```
sql, params = Model.objects.filter(...).exists().query.sql_with_params()
Model.objects.raw(sql, params=params)
```

Comment: `Model.objects.filter().exists()` will return a boolean value. and accessing .query() on boolean value will give `AttributeError`. or not?