# select_related queryset with ModelSerializer in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm trying to use the "select_related" queryset method with DRF serializers, 
but this example is still doing a lot of sql queries.

How can I get the related object "model_b" from select_related method?

```
class Model_A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    model_b = models.ForeignKey(Model_B, null=True, blank=True)

class Model_B(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Model_A_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_b = Model_B_Serializer(source="model_b")
    class Meta:
        model = Model_A
        fields = ('title', 'model_b')

class Model_B_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_B


class Model_A_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = Model_A_Serializer
    queryset = Model_A.objects.select_related('model_b').all()
```

Comment: There may be some problem with your actual code, but it should work fine as written above.  I'd need more info.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't included the SQL queries you're getting. Based on what you've written your code should work fine.

Answer (score 6):

[Use `prefetch_related` instead.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
queryset = Model_A.objects.all().prefetch_related('model_b')
```

Also, you can log your sql queries to the console with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11922878/20712)

Comment: prefetch_related isn't better applied to ManyToMany relationships?

Comment: I use it on ForeignKeys, ManyToMany, and inferred other-model `related_name` fields.  In debug mode, I print out all my sql queries.  When I used `prefetch_related` then all my tiny little one-entry requests on other models go away.  It only does one query on the related FK'd models with a large number of ids.

Comment: `select_related` should work fine in your situation  They behave a little differently: `select_related` will include model_b's in the original query via join, `prefetch_related` will run a single separate query for the model_b's using `WHERE ... IN ()`.