# Django+Raw Sql Query: See raw sql query running behind Django ORM in get method

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Trying to see the SQL query running behind each Django ORM.

For this I am doing:

```
item = Item.objects.filter(Id=8177).query
```

Here I am using filter to get multiple fetch.Above query gives me the desired output.

Now the problem starts, when I am trying to use get API

```
item = Item.objects.get(Id=8177).query
```

It fetches a single record then trying to see the raw SQL query running behind Django ORM then It displays like:

**AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'query'**

Doesn't Django support to see the Raw SQL query for get API? May be I am wrong.Can someone share some idea?

Comment: did you considered configuring SQL query logging? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20161527/3191896

Comment: Yes.That one is configured

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `django.db.connection.queries` to check db queries if you don't want to configure LOGGING:

```
from django import db
from app.models import MyModel

MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
print db.connection.queries

>>> [{'sql': 'Your query here', 'time': '0.001'}]
```

By the way, `get` method uses `filter` with slice from `_result_cache` under the hood and returns this slice. Also sometimes it also apply `order_by` to queryset. So you can almost always predict your SQL by checking query of `filter` method with same arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Does it impact on the query result set?

Comment: No, if I understand you. This list just contains executed queries as if you'd store them yourselve by appending str(query) to some arbitraty list

Comment: Thanks.Got it .Realy helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add a logger with name `django.db` in your `loggers` section of your logging configuration. Set its level to `DEBUG` and its handler to whichever handler you want to use. If you want your logs to show up in the test server startup screen itself, use the handler `console`. Make sure your Django app is running in DEBUG mode.

Example config:

```
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'verbose': {
                'format': '[%(thread)d %(threadName)s %(process)d %(processName)s][%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s in %(funcName)s] %(message)s'
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose',
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.db': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': False,
            }
        }
    }
```