# mongo:the return don't equal count()

Tags: django, mongodb

I have a problem that's been troubling me for a long time and it follows (code demo for example):

```
from mongoengine import*

Class Scan(Documnet):

      name=StringField()
      .....

queryset=Scan.objects.filter(name="Bob")

number1=queryset.count()

number2=len(queryset)
```

However，`number1=1782` and `number2=1668`, `number1 != number2`

Anyone can tell me the reason?

Comment: I would use DB queries logging (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375784/log-all-sql-queries) to figure out the difference between two methods and see where it all goes wrong.

Comment: thanks for you sharing ,but I am still in trouble.I can not catch that

Comment: Are you on a sharded  cluster?

Comment: @Styvane yep，I deploy mongo server in 4 service。is it data consistency problem？

Comment: That is the source of your problem

Comment: @Styvane so…what should I learn about to solve my problem？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is is due to one of the following reasons as mentioned in the [documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#sharded-clusters)

> On a sharded cluster, db.collection.count() can result in an inaccurate count if [orphaned documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-orphaned-document) exist or if a [chunk migration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/) is in progress.
>
> To avoid these situations, on a sharded cluster, use the $group stage of the `db.collection.aggregate()` method to $sum the documents. For example, the following operation counts the documents in a collection:

You can use the [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=aggregate#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate) method to do this as suggested in the documentation.

```
Scan.aggregate(
    {'$group': {
        '_id': None, 
        'count': {'$sum': 1}
    }}
)
```

Comment: You did me a big favor！ Thks!!