# Django 1.11 - how to print SQL statements with substituted variables

Tags: sql, django, debugging, logging

This question **is different** than [log all sql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375784/log-all-sql-queries/20161527)

I tried logging configurations from the answers above they are not working as I would like them to work, so please read on.

What I want to do, is to make Django (1.11.x) debug server log SQL queries in such a way, that I can redirect them to *.sql file and immediately execute.

For this I need a SQL statements where all the variables are already substituted, so I DON'T want this:

```
WHERE some_column in (:arg1, :arg2, ...)
```

but I want this instead:

```
WHERE some_column in ('actual_value_1', 'actual_value2', ...)
```

Can you please help me figure out how to do this?

1. Please note, that I don't want the SQL query to be printed in the browser (in some debug app like `django_debug_toolbar`) but printed to the console.
2. Please note, that I don't want to type Django QuerySet queries in console - I want to type URL in browser, so make an actual HTTP request to Django debug server and see it printing a SQL query in such a way I can execute it later using SQL Plus or any other console tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log all sql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375784/log-all-sql-queries)

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161527/548562

Comment: Sorry @IainShelvington,  I read both above threads and they don't answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the tool I just made would be perfect for you.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-print-sql

https://github.com/rabbit-aaron/django-print-sql

Install like this:

```
pip install --upgrade django-print-sql
```

Use like this in your view function:

```
from django_print_sql import print_sql

Class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        with print_sql():
            User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            # and more....
```

Comment: note: the count might not be accurate if multiple queries are executing across multiple threads.

Comment: Looks great! I like a context manager idea. Do you have decorators as well? Would be handy when you want to get all SQLs printed from a function.

Comment: I might add it on the next version

Comment: I've added the decorator in the 2018.3.6 version

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, because we have to strip the default `django.db.backends` log messages of the time taken and the args. After making these changes you should have a file of pure SQL that you are free to run as you wish...

First you want to set up your logging settings to reference our new log handler

Settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'sql': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'my_project.loggers.DjangoSQLFileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/sql.log'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['sql'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        }
    }

}
```

Then you need to define your new handler and strip out the unwanted text from the message.

`my_project.loggers.py`:

```
from logging import FileHandler


class DjangoSQLFileHandler(FileHandler):

    def getMessage(self):
        msg = super(DjangoSQLFileHandler, self).getMessage()
        return record.msg.split(') ', 1)[1].split(';', 1)[0] + ';'
```

Comment: It doesn't really work, I'm getting an exception: https://gist.github.com/mnowotka/9edfbc040c91c91bc04a2f18a074d7ed

Comment: I have updated my answer. My hack for changing the message was in the wrong place

Comment: I think you hack only works when you have a single place in SQL statement which refers to params.