# Django table rows are being magically hidden from ORM when I set a 'deleted' flag

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

Working in an inherited codebase.

I have a table with 2 objects when I look at it from the API or from the admin site, but it has 3 objects when I do a select * in PostgreSQL.

```
 name  |            created            | deleted
-------+-------------------------------+------------
 Sweet | 2017-07-21 16:31:28.556949-05 | t
 qwer  | 2017-07-21 16:36:03.096954-05 | t
 asdf  | 2017-07-21 16:35:15.585589-05 | f
(3 rows)
```

There is a 'deleted' flag in that table which appears to be an automagic soft-deletion flag. If I set the flag true through SQL, it's visible to ORM. If I set the flag false through SQL, it's hidden from ORM.

This particular type of automagic is extremely unhelpful and I want to disable it, but I'd like to understand how this works in Django before I go removing the column.

I am not using anything special to support this behavior. I have found articles which describe how to achieve soft deletion by subclassing special models that support it, but I'm doing none of that. This is just a vanilla subclass of models.Model. I have Googled and searched through the Django docs and I don't see anything that would indicate that just having a "deleted" column gives you soft deletion.

My questions are:

1. Does Django have some kind of automatic soft deletion support?
2. If so, where can I find the documentation?
3. If not, is there some other automatic mechanism I'm not understanding?

Comment: Django does not have built-in support for soft-deletion. This is most likely implemented using a custom `QuerySet` or `Manager` class. Look for an `objects` attribute on the model class, or anything that is set to a `QuerySet` or `Manager` instance.

Comment: @knbk Thank you, that was exactly what was going on. There was a Manager class associated with the model whose get_queryset() method filtered by deleted.

Comment: I log my SQL queries in dev mode.  You could probably get a better picture of what's going on that way: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375784/log-all-sql-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375784/log-all-sql-queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@knbk lead me to the answer:

There was a Manager class associated with the model whose get_queryset() method filtered any queryset operations by the 'deleted' flag.