# Log SQL queries even if DEBUG=False

Tags: django, logging, python-logging

This is my logging config in `settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs', 'django.log'),
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django.template': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'App': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

There's a behavior that I can't explain: if I run with `debug=True` I can see all SQL queries being logged to the console, but when `debug=False` that doesn't happen, even if I don't change the configuration above.

Why is this? How can I determine in my logging config whether or not SQL queries are logged to the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because existing loggers already filtered your logs. In this case is [Django's logger](http://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2/django/utils/log.py).

```py
DEFAULT_LOGGING = {
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    ...
}
```

and `django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue`

```py
class RequireDebugTrue(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return settings.DEBUG
```

To solve this issue, you could disable existing loggers by set  `disable_existing_loggers: True` or you can override the filter like so:

```py
LOGGING = {
    ...
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': [],
        },
    ...
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

Query logging goes way deeper as Django wraps the database cursor based on the truthiness of a computed property.

From [Line 226, django.db.backends.base.base v2.2.6 sources](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.6/django/db/backends/base/base.py#L226)

```
def _prepare_cursor(self, cursor):
    """
    Validate the connection is usable and perform database cursor wrapping.
    """
    self.validate_thread_sharing()
    if self.queries_logged:
        wrapped_cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(cursor)
    else:
        wrapped_cursor = self.make_cursor(cursor)
    return wrapped_cursor
```

This computed property gets to be decided on where debugging is forced or debugging is enabled in project settings

From [Line 149, django.db.backends.base.base v2.2.6 sources](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.6/django/db/backends/base/base.py#L149)

```
@property
def queries_logged(self):
    return self.force_debug_cursor or settings.DEBUG
```

You should be able to get a proxy to the default connection and force the debug cursor to be used.

```
from django.db import connection

connection.force_debug_cursor = True
```

I however advise against this approach and favor query audits in the database.

Comment: Following up a few years later - setting force_debug_cursor can be extremely useful if debugging an integration test failure, as you can set it and unset it around the single e.g. django.test.Client.post() call that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1: Write `patch_django` function in `patchers.py`

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/6/6
import importlib
import importlib.util
import sys


# noinspection DuplicatedCode
def patch_module(module_name, modification_func):
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(module_name)
    source = spec.loader.get_source(module_name)
    source = modification_func(source)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    code = compile(source, module.__spec__.origin, 'exec')
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
    sys.modules[module_name] = module
    return module


def patch_django():
    patch_module("django.db.backends.base.base", lambda x: x.replace(
        "self.force_debug_cursor = False",
        "self.force_debug_cursor = True"))
```

### Step2: Call `patch_django` before `django` imported.

**manage.py**

```py
__import__("importlib").import_module("patchers").patch_django()  # noqa
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**wsgi.py**

```py
__import__("importlib").import_module("patchers").patch_django()  # noqa
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**asgi.py**

```py
__import__("importlib").import_module("patchers").patch_django()  # noqa
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
```

### Step 3: Make sure `django.db.backends` is in debug level

```py
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
```