# Count number of queries with DEBUG=False

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, django-rest-framework

In my Django application, I want to count the number of queries made by each endpoint. I want to run this in production, so I cannot rely on any of the techniques I found with regular Django SQL logging that is only enabled when DEBUG=True, like [adding a SQL logger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161527/1469465) or relying on `django.db.connection.queries`. Is there a context manager that works similar to `self.assertNumQueries()` in test cases that can be run in production like this?

```
def my_view(request):
    with count_sql_queries() as nr_queries:
        response = business_logic()
    logger.debug(f'There were {nr_queries} queries made')
    return response
```

Comment: Have you looked at doing this using the database logs?

Comment: What do you mean with "the database logs"?

Comment: You can probably do this in a middleware, and then write a [`db connection execute wrapper`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/instrumentation/#connection-execute-wrapper) to increment some counter everytime a database query is done

Comment: I hadn't heard of execute_wrapper before, thanks! Unfortunately, this also only executes when DEBUG=True.

Comment: *transaction logs.  

- mysql ; https://github.com/Yelp/ybinlogp OR  site:github.com mysql+binlog+reader  
- postgres ; site:github.com postgres+log+reader

Comment: @EM28: As far as I understand it, those are tools to work with the existing database logs, right? That is not exactly what I was looking for, since it has no direct connection with the code base itself, so you cannot easily build decorators like I intend to.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58396629

Answer (score 1):

This implementation makes use of [Django Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/) and docs on [Database Instrumentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/instrumentation/), which was released with Django 2.0.
It looks something like the following:

```
import time

from datadog import statsd
from django.db import connection
from django.urls import resolve


class SQLPerformanceMetrics:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.elapsed_query_time = 0.0

    def __call__(self, execute, sql, params, many, context):
        start_time = time.time()
        try:
            return execute(sql, params, many, context)
        finally:
            self.count += 1
            self.elapsed_query_time += time.time() - start_time


class SQLPerformanceMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        metrics = SQLPerformanceMetrics()
        with connection.execute_wrapper(metrics):
            response = self.get_response(request)

        tags = [f"endpoint:{resolve(request.path).route}"]
        statsd.distribution("api.total_sql_queries", metrics.count, tags=tags)
        statsd.timing("api.time_elapsed_sql_queries", metrics.elapsed_query_time, tags=tags)

        return response
```

Note that this uses similar mechanisms to popular libraries like [`django-zen-queries`](https://github.com/dabapps/django-zen-queries/tree/master).