# Django does not filter by non english letters

Tags: python, html, django

In my database I have objects with slavic letters (śćę etc.). It is displayed correctly in my database, admin panel and even when I call my object in template. User can search for this object by providing what he wants in text input box: `template.html`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Model" name="searched_model" id="searched_model" value="">
```

Hovewer when I filter the objects database in my view: `views.py`

```
found_products = ProductBase.objects.filter(Q(model__contains=searched_model).order_by('model')
```

It filters and displays correctly until slavic letter is provided.
For example, user wants object with model property as: `ObjectŚĆobject`
If he writes in my search field `object` it will find and display `ObjectŚĆobject`.
But if he writes `objectŚ` or even `Ś` only it will not show anything.

My view returns `found_products` to template and displays it in table: `template.html`

```
{% for item in found_products %}
...
<td>
    {{item.model}}
</td>
```

I don't know where lies the problem. In `settings.py` I have correct `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl-pl'`.

EDIT:
I did some logging and when I display searched phrase it shows correct string.
When I log the queryset after `filter` it shows empty queryset. So the problem definitely lies in filtering data.

EDIT2:
When using other logging method I can see the `SELECT` query as below when searching for `nieokreś`:

```
(0.000) SELECT "zam_produktbase"."id", "zam_produktbase"."ean", "zam_produktbase"."model", "zam_produktbase"."kolor", "zam_produktbase"."symbol", "zam_produktbase"."aktywny", "zam_produktbase"."zam_id" FROM "zam_produktbase" WHERE ("za
m_produktbase"."model" LIKE '%nieokreś%' ESCAPE '\' AND "zam_produktbase"."symbol" LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '\' AND "zam_produktbase"."kolor" LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '\') ORDER BY "zam_produktbase"."model" ASC; args=('%nieokreś%', '%%', '%%')
```

EDIT3:
Looks like the problem is in my sqlite database. When doing SELECT query it doesn't find non english letters.

EDIT4:
It was a problem with capital letters, different filtering fixed the problem.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: It's SQLite3 for now

Comment: Sounds like an encoding mismatch. What encoding is the data and what is set for Django?

Comment: @KlausD. Honestly, I did not interfere in default settings. I don't know where in settings should I look for it.

Comment: @KlausD. I did some logging and when I display searched phrase it shows correct string.
When I log the queryset after `filter` it shows empty queryset. So the problem definitely lies in filtering data.

Comment: A common misconception in Django is that the chain contain actual items in every step. The whole chain does no more than collecting information and at a later time (usually when you iterate over the queryset) this information is transformed into a query send to the database. You should try to [log the actual queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56773783/3929826).

Comment: @KlausD. Did not know that. Thanks. When using this method I can see

 > SELECT "zam_produktbase"."id", "zam_produktbase"."ean",
> "zam_produktbase"."model", "zam_produktbase"."kolor",
> "zam_produktbase"."symbol", "zam_produktbase"."aktywny",
> "zam_produktbase"."zam_id" FROM "zam_produktbase" WHERE ("za
> m_produktbase"."model" LIKE '%nieokreś%' ESCAPE '\' AND
> "zam_produktbase"."symbol" LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '\' AND
> "zam_produktbase"."kolor" LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '\') ORDER BY
> "zam_produktbase"."model" ASC; args=('%nieokreś%', '%%', '%%')

Comment: Please add all relevant details to the question itself.