# Endpoint with very slow response with DRF when receiving a parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am using Django REST framework for my API and I start using filters, depending on the value, it make various count, but it take at least 3 minutes everytime I make a response.

The serealizer use the **context['request']** to get the url parameter and filter for the result

```
class CheetosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    
    total_cheetos = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    cheetos_on_sale = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    cheetos_on_stock = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
 
    class Meta:
        model = Cheetos 
        fields = (
            'total_cheetos'
            ,'cheetos_on_sale'
            ,'cheetos_on_stock'           
        )
        read_only_fields = fields

   def get_total_cheetos(self,obj):

        request_object = self.context['request']
        customer_id = request_object.query_params.get('Shop__id_Cat_Customer')
        
        if customer_id is None:
            return Cheetos.objects.filter(Estatus=3).count()
        else:
            return Cheetos.objects.filter(Estatus=3,Shop__id_Cat_Customer = customer_id).count()
    
    def get_cheetos_on_sale(self,obj):
        request_object = self.context['request']
        customer_id = request_object.query_params.get('Shop__id_Cat_Customer')

        if customer_id is None:
            return Cheetos.objects.filter(Estatus=3, id_Cat = 1).count()
        else:
            return Cheetos.objects.filter(Estatus=3, id_Cat = 1,Shop__id_Cat_Customer = customer_id).count()

    def get_cheetos_on_stock(self,obj):
        request_object = self.context['request']
        customer_id = request_object.query_params.get('Shop__id_Cat_Customer')

        if customer_id is None:
            return Cheetos.objects.filter(Estatus=3, id_Cat = 2).count()
        else:
            return Cheetos.objects.filter(Estatus=3, id_Cat = 2,Shop__id_Cat_Customer = customer_id).count()
```

On the view is where I set the filterset parameter

```
class CheetosView(DefaultViewSetMixin):
    filterset_fields = ['Shop__id_Cat_Customer']
    queryset =  Cheetos.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CheetosSerializer
```

And I use postman to validate the data, and here it says the time it takes with the correct values I´m looking for:
[Postman Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4lcE.png)

Is there a way to make this much better?

Comment: Generally speaking select "count(*) from table" - may have big problems with bigger data gets

Comment: You should look at all the underlying queries by printing your generated SQL to the terminal.   See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56773783/20712