# Getting OperationalError: (2000, 'Unknown MySQL error') when accessing mysql database using celery and django

Tags: mysql, django, celery, mysql-python, django-celery

I am using celery with my django application. My application works fine with mysql database, but I am getting `(2000, 'Unknown MySQL error')` when celery tries to access the database. This happens only when I run celery in a container, when I run it in my ubuntu machine, it works fine.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
[2022-06-18 13:39:33,717: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task taskMonitor.tasks.monitor[7e6696aa-d602-4336-a582-4c719f8d72df] raised unexpected: OperationalError(2000, 'Unknown MySQL error')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2000, 'Unknown MySQL error')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 451, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 734, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/taskMonitor/tasks.py", line 18, in monitor
    for obj in objs.iterator():
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 401, in _iterator
    yield from self._iterable_class(
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1361, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2000, 'Unknown MySQL error')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it using a comment from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66185491/1543532). I added 'latin1' as a charset in my database definition, and it solved the problem:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'HOST': DB_URL,
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD':  DB_PASSWORD,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'latin1'
        }           
    }
}
```