# django select_for_update acquires relation lock

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm, select-for-update

I have this code sample that should take row (tuple) lock in postgres, however it seems to take table (relation) lock instead:

```
with transaction.Atomic(savepoint=True, durable=False):
    record = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk='1234')
    record.delete()
    time.sleep(5)
    raise Exception
```

By looking at the pg_locks during the time of the transaction I can see:

```
select locktype, database, relation::regclass, pid, mode, granted from pg_locks where pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

[image]

To my knowledge, I should have seen "tuple" in the locktype since I'm only locking specific row/s and not the entire table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First things first

You actually did not perform a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` query.

- `record = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk='1234')` returns a `QuerySet`, no query is executed.

  - `record.delete()` only executes a `DELETE` command.
- A `SELECT FOR UPDATE` query would have acquired a `relation` `RowShareLock`.

  - You can verify this by executing the `QuerySet` with `.first()`, i.e. `record = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk='1234').first()`.
- You can verify this with [log all sql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161527/8601760).

## Row-level (tuple) locks

A row-level `FOR UPDATE` lock is acquired but not shown in your `pg_locks` view (it doesn't show on mine too). Instead, we see `transactionid` `ExclusiveLock` (and `virtualxid` `ExclusiveLock`).

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/view-pg-locks.html:

> Although tuples are a lockable type of object, information about row-level locks is stored on disk, not in memory, and therefore row-level locks normally do not appear in this view. If a transaction is waiting for a row-level lock, it will usually appear in the view as waiting for the permanent transaction ID of the current holder of that row lock.

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/explicit-locking.html:

> `FOR UPDATE`
>
> ...
>
> The `FOR UPDATE` lock mode is also acquired by any `DELETE` on a row ...

You can verify this empirically by running in your psql terminal:

- before `record.delete()`

  - `SELECT FROM mymodel WHERE id='1' FOR UPDATE;` works.
  - `SELECT FROM mymodel WHERE id='1234' FOR UPDATE;` works.
- after `record.delete()`

  - `SELECT FROM mymodel WHERE id='1' FOR UPDATE;` works.
  - `SELECT FROM mymodel WHERE id='1234' FOR UPDATE;` doesn't work.

## Table-level (relation) locks

1. The `relation` `AccessShareLock` appears to be acquired for a `SELECT` query that you did not show in your code sample, e.g. `MyModel.objects.filter(pk='1234').first()`.
2. The `relation` `RowExclusiveLock` is acquired for the `DELETE` command.

While these are table-level locks, they only conflict with `EXCLUSIVE` and/or `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` locks, which are not acquired by most other DQL (data query language) and DML (data manipulation language) commands.

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/explicit-locking.html:

> `ACCESS SHARE`
>
> Conflicts with the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock mode only.
>
> The `SELECT` command acquires a lock of this mode on referenced tables. In general, any query that only reads a table and does not modify it will acquire this lock mode.

> `ROW EXCLUSIVE`
>
> Conflicts with the `EXCLUSIVE` and `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock modes.
>
> The commands `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and `INSERT` acquire this lock mode on the target table (in addition to `ACCESS SHARE` locks on any other referenced tables). In general, this lock mode will be acquired by any command that modifies data in a table.

Comment: Thanks @aaron for explaining. Indeed, I changed the snippet and therefore you cannot see the AccessShareLock. Just imagine I have there get() instead of filter()...

To summer up, according to your writing, I actually have two different locks level at the same time. First is on the rows (which I cannot see in the pg_locks) while the second is on the table (as "RowExclusiveLock')?

Comment: Yes, that's right.