# django raw sql in models with ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Let's say this pseudocode represents models to work with

```
class Quiz():
    name = models.CharField()

class Answer():
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    answer_text = models.CharField()
```

I would like to trace raw SQL, so let's also import `from django.db import connection`

```
print(Answer.objects.all().select_related('quiz').query)
```

ok, here we have inner join under the hood

```
>>> a = Answer.objects.all()
>>> print(a[0].quiz.query)
```

however the latter example throws `AttributeError: 'Quiz' object has no attribute 'query'`

Could you tell if there are any ways of tracing raw sql more effectively? Which way is the best?
I'm practicing more complicated `prefetch_related` and `select_related` queries.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding debug logging for your db https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161527/4151233? Or using the django debug toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

What This line `a[0].quiz.query` is trying to do is find a field name `query` in the model Quiz

`.query` only works with all() & filter(),

Comment: problem solved using django-debug-toolbar, thanks

Comment: That's great, keep it up :)