# Django CaptureQueriesContext can't see my objects filter query in captures_queries

Tags: python, django

I want to log the raw SQL statements in my Django testcases.
I can see the INSERT sql statements, but I can't see the SELECT sql statements in the log.

I want to see every SQL statement in the log, whether it is CREATE, SELECT, UPDATE or something else.

**Output**

```
$ python manage.py test
<OUTPUT OMITTED>
Found 1 test(s).
Running tests...
----------------------------------------------------------------------

[{'sql': 'INSERT INTO "myapp_testtabletwo" ("test_field") VALUES (\'abc\') RETURNING "myapp_testtabletwo"."id"', 'time': '0.001'}]
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.113s

OK

Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Closing active connection
```

**tests.py**

```
from django.db import connection
from my_app.models import TestTableTwo

class DatabaseExampleTests(TestCase):
    databases = '__all__'

    def test_example(self):
        with CaptureQueriesContext(connection) as ctx:
            created_object = TestTableTwo.objects.create(test_field="abc")
            all_objects = TestTableTwo.objects.all()
        print(ctx.captured_queries)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class TestTableTwo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    test_field = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': "testpostgres",
        'USER': "postgres,
        'PASSWORD': "password",
        'HOST': "postgres"
    }
}
```

**Version**

```
$ python -V
Python 3.9.15

$ pip list 
# output omitted
Package                Version
---------------------- ---------
Django                 4.1
psycopg2               2.9.5
```

**Edit:**
When I change `all_objects = TestTableTwo.objects.all()` to `print(TestTableTwo.objects.all())`, I see the SELECT sql statement in the log.
But I don't understand the reason, why it works with the `print()` statement.

Comment: you mean whenever there's query made from `ORM` you want to see that `raw sql` in terminal?

Comment: @HemalPatel Correct, my expectation is to see each `raw sql` in `ctx.captured_queries`

Comment: i think you can use this to watch all the queries in The Terminal. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161527/16250404) Yes it works i just tried.

Comment: @HemalPatel Unfortunately I got the same behavior. I can see the INSERT statements, but can't see the SELECT statement in the logs. I tried your example

Answer (score 0):

here put this in `settings.py`:
you can check `select` queries in the terminal.

```
import os

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same behavior. I cann see INSERT, but not SELECT
`(0.001) INSERT INTO "myapp_testtabletwo" ("test_field",) VALUES ('abc',) RETURNING "myapp_testtabletwo"."id"; args=('abc',); alias=default`

Comment: @Ewro Weird :'). i just created demo project and it showing all the queries.

Comment: Strangely enough, I can see the SELECT query, when I use print() `print(TestTableTwo.objects.all())`

Comment: @Ewro my bad. I was using it the same way. Just noticed. You have to use `print`. Still will check if I can find a better way.