How to start and complete an atomic transaction in MySQL by using Django 5.0.3?
I want to save a CSV (with 50k rows) as a MySQL table in Django. I wrote the model and I started the atomic transaction from the post request (runned by ajax async submit from the template). The problem is that the transaction is interrupted by the StateReloader and it does not continues. Is it possible to run the transaction in background and let it to complete?
Here a small version of my code:
# file: models.py


from django.db import models, transaction

class MyManager(models.Manager):
    @transaction.atomic
    def create_models(self, file, callback=None):
        if callback is not None:
            transaction.on_commit(callback)
        with open(file, "r") as fp:
            lines = map(str.strip, fp.readlines())
            lines = map(lambda x: x.split(";"), lines)
            lines = list(lines)
        headers = lines[0]
        print("Writing table with {} lines...".format(len(lines) - 1)) # 50k lines
        for i, line in enumerate(lines[1:]):
            for j in range(len(headers)):
                print("Saving line #{}".format(i), end="\r").          # ends at line 800 before the StateReloader
                self.create(row=i + 1, header=headers[j], value=line[j])
        print()
        return True


class MyModel(models.Model):
    row = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    header = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    objects = MyManager()
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.header} = {self.value} on row {self.row}"

# file: views.py


from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


from .models import MyModel


def end_transaction():
    print("Done!")


class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "edit_csv.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        filename = request.POST.get("filename", "").strip()
        if filename != "":
            filename = os.path.basename(filename)
            routine = MyModel.objects.create_models(filename, end_transaction)
        return JsonResponse(self.render_to_response(context), safe=False)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context


I don't think you need a transaction here, you can insert all records in the same query.

I don't think the problem is with the transaction, you can create the records efficiently in bulk with:
import csv


class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'edit_csv.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        filename = request.POST.get('filename', '').strip()
        if filename != '':
            with open(os.path.basename(filename), 'r') as f:
                csv = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
                MyModel.objects.bulk_create(
                    [
                        MyModel(row=row, header=header, value=value)
                        for row, data in enumerate(csv, 1)
                        for header, value in data.items()
                    ]
                )
        return JsonResponse(self.render_to_response(context), safe=False)
We here thus first create a large list of items to insert, and then add these all with one (or a few queries) to the database. This will likely also speed up the process immensely.

First of all, thank you for your answer. In this case bulk_create works, but what if the data is more than this? The StateRealoder could be executed before the end of the request, right?

@G.F.: a tranaction will just in that case abort the transaction, such that either it succeeds completely, or in case of a state reload is done, fail (completely). You can wrap the bulk_create in a transactional context though. But that will only be useful if there is a batch size, and unless you use SQLite, .bulk_create will always do all records in one query. So the state reloader could be executed before the end of the request, and then no rows are added.

Finally the statreload is not something to consider much, since this is just when you change a *.py file in development (DEBUG = True), not in production.

However, I would like the task to be running asynchronously and in background so that I can do something else. I have already written an AdminModel to check if the process has been completed. How do I do that?

@G.F: the bottleneck is not the query, the bottleneck is python reading the file into memory and processing.

No, the bottleneck is not python reading the file in memory. I tried without it and the bulk_create is still slow while connecting to the database locally.

@G.F: do you see the queries passing between the Django layer and the database? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161527/67579 I suspect an N+1 problem.

Yes, but I do not see anything strange

@G.F: you can also use .abulk_create, so use the assynchronic framework.

I solved it by running a parallel thread. In any other case, the wait time was excessive.
