# aggregate() vs annotate() in Django

Tags: python, django, aggregate, django-queryset, django-annotate

Django's `QuerySet` has two methods, `annotate` and `aggregate`. The documentation says that:

> Unlike aggregate(), annotate() is not a terminal clause. The output of the annotate() clause is a QuerySet.
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset

Is there any other difference between them? If not, then why does `aggregate` exist?

Comment: Can you please add the link to this statement in the docs?

Comment: added link to docs

Answer (score 292):

I would focus on the example queries rather than your quote from the documentation. `Aggregate` calculates values for the **entire** queryset. `Annotate` calculates summary values for **each item** in the queryset.

## Aggregation

```
>>> Book.objects.aggregate(average_price=Avg('price'))
{'average_price': 34.35}
```

Returns a dictionary containing the average price of **all** books in the queryset.

## Annotation

```
>>> q = Book.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors'))
>>> q[0].num_authors
2
>>> q[1].num_authors
1
```

`q` is the queryset of books, but each book has been annotated with the number of authors.

Comment: Am I correct that `.annotate()` on a qs alone does not hit the db, but calling `q[0].num_authors` does? I assume `aggregate` must always hit the db as it is a terminal clause?

Comment: @alias51 that's really related to the original question, so I don't think the comments on an eight-year-old question is the best place to ask. If you want to check when the queries run, then you can [check `connection.queries`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running). Hint: check whether it's the `book = q[0]` or ` book.num_authors` that causes the query.

Answer (score 43):

**Aggregate**
Aggregate generate result (summary) values over an entire QuerySet. 
Aggregate operate over the rowset to get a single value from the rowset.(For example sum of all prices in the rowset). Aggregate is applied on entire QuerySet and  it generate result (summary) values over an entire QuerySet.

In Model:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
```

In Shell:

```
>>> Books.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('price'))
# Above code will give the Average of the price Column 
>>> {'price__avg': 34.35}
```

**Annotate**
Annotate generate an independent summary for each object in a QuerySet.(We can say it iterate each object in a QuerySet and apply operation)

In Model:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=52, verbose_name='Name')
    video = models.FileField(upload_to=document_path, verbose_name='Upload 
               video')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Created by', 
                       related_name="create_%(class)s")
    user_likes = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, null=True, 
                  blank=True, help_text='User can like once', 
                         verbose_name='Like by')
```

In View:

```
videos = Video.objects.values('id', 'name','video').annotate(Count('user_likes',distinct=True)
```

**In view it will count the likes for each video**

Comment: why `distinct=True` is required in last example?

Comment: @YuriyLeonov distinct=True used for that the operation perform on distinct value. It's not related to the current question asked. Sorry for that Actually I have used on my code.

Answer (score 23):

That's the main difference, but aggregates also work on a grander scale than annotations. Annotations are inherently related to individual items in a queryset. If you run an `Count` annotation on a something like a many-to-many field, you'll get a separate count for each member of the queryset (as an added attribute). If you were to do the same with an aggregation, however, it would attempt to count every relationship on *every* member of the queryset, even duplicates, and return that as just one value.

Comment: Am I correct that `.annotate()` on a qs alone does not hit the db, but calling the result of an annotation such as `q[0].num_authors` does? I assume `aggregate` must always hit the db as it is a terminal clause?

Answer (score 7):

- [aggregate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.aggregate) can calculates all values of the current model's column. *A dictionary is returned.
- [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) can calculates all values of the child model's column accessed by foreign key. *A QuerySet is returned.

*[Avg()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#avg), [Count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#id9), [Max()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#max), [Min()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#min), [Sum()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#sum) and so on can be used with `aggregate()` and `annotate()`.

For example, there are `Category` and `Product` models below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
```

And, there are `Category` and `Product` admins below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Product 

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name')
    ordering = ('id',)

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'category_id', 'category', 'name', 'price')
    ordering = ('id',)
```

And, there are 2 categories below:

[image]

And, there are 5 products below:

[image]

And, there is `test` view below:

```py
# "views.py"

from .models import Category, Product
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db.models import Avg
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models import Min
from django.db.models import Sum

def test(request):
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

First, I explain about `aggregate()`.

## aggregate():

Now, I run `test` view which has **the columns `id`, `category` and `price`** in [Avg()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#avg), [Count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#id9), [Max()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#max), [Min()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#min) and [Sum()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#sum) in `aggregate()` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):

    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Avg('id')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Count('id')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Max('id')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Min('id')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Sum('id')))
    print()
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Avg('category')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Count('category')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Max('category')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Min('category')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Sum('category')))
    print()
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Avg('price')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Count('price')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Max('price')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Min('price')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Sum('price')))
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, these dictionaries below are outputted on console:

```
{'id__avg': 3.0}
{'id__count': 5}
{'id__max': 5}
{'id__min': 1}
{'id__sum': 15}

{'category__avg': 1.4}
{'category__count': 5}
{'category__max': 2}
{'category__min': 1}
{'category__sum': 7}

{'price__avg': Decimal('30.0000000000000000')}
{'price__count': 5}
{'price__max': Decimal('50.00')}
{'price__min': Decimal('10.00')}
{'price__sum': Decimal('150.00')}
```

And, `aggregate()` can accept multiple kinds of columns and functions in any order, the multiple same kind of columns and functions and no columns and functions as shown below. *The multiple same kind of columns and functions are made into one and no columns and functions get an empty dictionary:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):
    # Multiple kinds of columns and functions in any order
    print(
        Product.objects.aggregate(
            Max('price'), Max('category'), Sum('id'), Min('id')
        )
    )

    # The multiple same kind of columns and functions
    print(
        Product.objects.aggregate(
            Sum('price'), Sum('price'), Sum('price')
        )
    )

    # No columns and functions
    print(Product.objects.aggregate())
        
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, these dictionaries below are outputted on console:

```
{'price__max': Decimal('50.00'), 'category__max': 2, 'id__sum': 15, 'id__min': 1}
{'price__sum': Decimal('150.00')}
{}
```

And, `Max()` and `Min()` below can accept **non-numeric types**:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):

    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Count('name')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Max('name')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Min('name')))
        
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, these dictionaries below are outputted on console:

```
{'name__count': 5}
{'name__max': 'Tea'}
{'name__min': 'Apple'}
```

But, `Avg()` and `Sum()` below cannot accept **non-numeric types**:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):

    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Avg('name')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(Sum('name')))
        
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

So, the errors below occur:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function avg(character varying) does not exist

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function sum(character varying) does not exist

And, you can change the default key names as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):

    print(Product.objects.aggregate(priceAve=Avg('price')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(priceCount=Count('price')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(priceMax=Max('price')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(priceMin=Min('price')))
    print(Product.objects.aggregate(priceSum=Sum('price')))
        
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, the default key names are changed as shown below:

```
{'priceAve': Decimal('30.0000000000000000')}
{'priceCount': 5}
{'priceMax': Decimal('50.00')}
{'priceMin': Decimal('10.00')}
{'priceSum': Decimal('150.00')}
```

Next, I explain about `annotate()`.

## annotate():

Now, I run `test` view which has **the columns `product__id`, `product__category` and `product__price`** in `Avg()`, `Count()`, `Max()`, `Min()` and `Sum()` in `annotate()` as shown below. *You need to put `__avg`, `__count`, `__max`, `__min` and `__sum` to `product__id`, `product__category` and `product__price` for `Avg()`, `Count()`, `Max()`, `Min()` and `Sum()` respectively:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):

    qs = Category.objects.annotate(
        Avg('product__id'), 
        Count('product__id'), 
        Max('product__id'), 
        Min('product__id'), 
        Sum('product__id')
    ).order_by('pk')

    for obj in qs:
        print(
            obj.id, 
            obj.name, 
            obj.product__id__avg, 
            obj.product__id__count, 
            obj.product__id__max, 
            obj.product__id__min, 
            obj.product__id__sum
        )

    print()

    qs = Category.objects.annotate(
        Avg('product__category'), 
        Count('product__category'), 
        Max('product__category'), 
        Min('product__category'), 
        Sum('product__category')
    ).order_by('pk')

    for obj in qs:
        print(
            obj.id, 
            obj.name, 
            obj.product__category__avg, 
            obj.product__category__count, 
            obj.product__category__max, 
            obj.product__category__min, 
            obj.product__category__sum
        )

    print()

    qs = Category.objects.annotate(
        Avg('product__price'), 
        Count('product__price'), 
        Max('product__price'), 
        Min('product__price'), 
        Sum('product__price')
    ).order_by('pk')

    for obj in qs:
        print(
            obj.id, 
            obj.name, 
            obj.product__price__avg, 
            obj.product__price__count, 
            obj.product__price__max, 
            obj.product__price__min, 
            obj.product__price__sum
        )
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
1 Food 2.0 3 3 1 6
2 Drink 4.5 2 5 4 9

1 Food 1.0 3 1 1 3
2 Drink 2.0 2 2 2 4

1 Food 20.0000000000000000 3 30.00 10.00 60.00
2 Drink 45.0000000000000000 2 50.00 40.00 90.00
```

And, the query without [order_by('pk')](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) below makes the order descendant:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):

    qs = Category.objects.annotate(
        Avg('product__price'), 
        Count('product__price'), 
        Max('product__price'), 
        Min('product__price'), 
        Sum('product__price')
    ) # Without ".order_by('pk')"

    for obj in qs:
        print(
            obj.id, 
            obj.name, 
            obj.product__price__avg, 
            obj.product__price__count, 
            obj.product__price__max, 
            obj.product__price__min, 
            obj.product__price__sum
        )
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, the order is descendant as shown below:

```
2 Drink 4.5 2 5 4 9
1 Food 2.0 3 3 1 6
```

And, **empty `annotate()`** below has `id` and `name` attributes:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request): 
                         # Empty "annotate()"
    qs = Category.objects.annotate().order_by('pk')

    for obj in qs:
        print(obj.id, obj.name)
        
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
1 Food
2 Drink
```

But, **empty `annotate()`** below doesn't have `__avg`, `__count`, `__max`, `__min` and `__sum` attributes as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request): 
                         # Empty "annotate()"
    qs = Category.objects.annotate().order_by('pk')
    
    for obj in qs:
        print(
            obj.product__price__avg,
            obj.product__price__count,
            obj.product__price__max,
            obj.product__price__min,
            obj.product__price__sum,
        )
        
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

So, the errors below occur:

> AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute 'product__price__avg'

> AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute 'product__price__count'

> AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute 'product__price__max'

> AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute 'product__price__min'

> AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute 'product__price__sum'

And, `Max()` and `Min()` below can accept **non-numeric types**:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):

    qs = Category.objects.annotate(
        Count('product__name'), 
        Max('product__name'), 
        Min('product__name'), 
    ).order_by('pk')

    for obj in qs:
        print( 
            obj.product__name__count, 
            obj.product__name__max, 
            obj.product__name__min, 
        )

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
3 Orange Apple
2 Tea Milk
```

But, `Avg()` and `Sum()` below cannot accept **non-numeric types**:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):

    qs = Category.objects.annotate(
        Avg('product__name'),
        Sum('product__name')
    ).order_by('pk')

    for obj in qs:
        print( 
            obj.product__name__avg, 
            obj.product__name__sum
        )
        
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

So, the errors below occur:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function avg(character varying) does not exist

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function sum(character varying) does not exist

And, you can change the default attribute names as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

# ...

def test(request):

    qs = Category.objects.annotate(
        productPriceAvg=Avg('product__price'), 
        productPriceCount=Count('product__price'), 
        productPriceMax=Max('product__price'), 
        productPriceMin=Min('product__price'), 
        productPriceSum=Sum('product__price')
    ).order_by('pk')

    for obj in qs:
        print(
            obj.id, 
            obj.name, 
            obj.productPriceAvg, 
            obj.productPriceCount, 
            obj.productPriceMax, 
            obj.productPriceMin, 
            obj.productPriceSum
        )
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
1 Food 20.0000000000000000 3 30.00 10.00 60.00
2 Drink 45.0000000000000000 2 50.00 40.00 90.00
```