# How to query as GROUP BY two table in django?

Tags: python, django

How do I use the django query?
The following is a written sql statement：

```
SELECT a.name, count(uri_id) as counts from interface_uri a LEFT JOIN interface_interfacetestcase b on a.id = b.uri_id GROUP BY a.name, a.version_id;
```

Comment: Helio, you can use annotate or aggregate. Here the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981837/difference-between-djangos-annotate-and-aggregate-methods

Comment: I am sorry, in the same data sheet inquiries I will be, but in the two tables between the joint query and seeking do not know what method?
For example, between a table to write:
`Uri.objects.values('name').annotate(count=Count('name'))`
How to write between the two?