# Django ORM Group By ID

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

I am trying to get some information from my table; total price, total trip etc between two dates. Here is my query

```
start_date = Utils.subtract_day(datetime.datetime.today(), 30)
end_date = datetime.datetime.today()
trips = TbPastTrips.objects.filter(identity=identity, creation_time__range=(start_date, end_date),
                                   status=TripStatus.PAYMENT_COMPLETED)\
    .annotate(total_price__=Sum('price'), total_tip=Sum('tip_amount'),
              total_additional_fees=Sum('additional_fees'), total_trip=Count('price')) \
    .values('total_price__', 'total_tip', 'total_additional_fees', 'total_trip')

print(trips.query)
```

This is the raw sql query that I expect from above queryset:

```
SELECT SUM(`tb_past_trips`.`PRICE`) AS `total_price__`, SUM(`tb_past_trips`.`TIP_AMOUNT`) AS `total_tip`, SUM(`tb_past_trips`.`ADDITIONAL_FEES`) AS `total_additional_fees`, COUNT(`tb_past_trips`.`PRICE`) AS `total_trip` FROM `tb_past_trips` WHERE (`tb_past_trips`.`IDENTITY` = 44444444444 AND `tb_past_trips`.`CREATION_TIME` BETWEEN '2017-08-29 10:36:19.446371' AND '2017-09-28 10:36:19.446405' AND `tb_past_trips`.`STATUS` = 4)
```

But it adds below extra query:

> GROUP BY `tb_past_trips`.`ID` ORDER BY NULL

to end of the query. But I don't want to group it.

So what is the wrong thing that i am doing?

Django version :(1, 11, 5, 'final', 0)

Python 3.6.2

Added Model:

```
class TbPastTrips(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    transaction_id = models.CharField(db_column='TRANSACTION_ID', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    identity = models.CharField(db_column='TAXI', max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    price = models.IntegerField(db_column='PRICE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    tip_amount = models.IntegerField(db_column='TIP_AMOUNT', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    additional_fees = models.IntegerField(db_column='ADDITIONAL_FEES', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    total_price = models.IntegerField(db_column='TOTAL_PRICE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(db_column='CREATION_TIME')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tb_past_trips'
```

Comment: what is your model? how did you manged it? is it database view?

Comment: I found it, missusage, i must use aggregation not annotate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981837/difference-between-djangos-annotate-and-aggregate-methods

Comment: good if it help you, any way you can add answer on your question it can help others

Comment: someone already answered it, i will vote it

Answer (score 1):

you just need added empty order by `.order_by()` 
more details [default-ordering-or-order-by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by)

Comment: added your models please, i try it

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation not annotate,

> Per-object summaries can be generated using the annotate() clause.
>   When an annotate() clause is specified, each object in the QuerySet
>   will be annotated with the specified values.

Aggregation

> What we need is a way to calculate summary values over the objects
>   that belong to this QuerySet. This is done by appending an aggregate()
>   clause onto the QuerySet