# Django template and loop over list of elements

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to loop over some objects placed into a list and get statistics on each one.
I'm using `Django 1.11.16`

User can select one or multiple publication(s) and I display some statistics  over each publication in the list.

I have a view part which looks like this :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    publication_list = self.request.GET.getlist('publication_list')

    publication_selected = Publication.objects.filter(id__in=publication_list)

    download_all_period = Download.objects.values('usage', 'doc__publication__pub_id') \
                    .filter(
                        doc__publication__id__in=publication_list) \
                    .filter(
                        Q(creation_date__gte=start_date) & Q(creation_date__lte=end_date))\
                    .aggregate(
                        nusage=Sum('usage'))

    request_all_period = Download.objects.values('doc__publication__pub_id')\
                    .filter(
                        doc__publication__id__in=publication_list)\
                    .filter(
                        Q(creation_date__gte=start_date) & Q(creation_date__lte=end_date))

    all_period_list = zip(publication_selected, download_all_period, request_all_period)

    context_data['publication_list'] = publication_list
    context_data['publication_selected'] = publication_selected
    context_data['download_all_period'] = download_all_period
    context_data['request_all_period'] = request_all_period
    context_data['all_period_list'] = all_period_list

return context_data
```

Then I have a template, with a table. So I would like to loop over each element in my list in order to create one row per element :

```
{% for publication_selected, download_all_period, request_all_period in all_period_list %}
  {% if download_all_period.nusage %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ start_date|date:"Y/m/d" }} to {{ end_date|date:"Y/m/d" }}</td>
      <td>{{ publication_selected }}</td>
      <td><span class="badge alert-danger">{{ download_all_period.nusage }}</span> / <span
        class="badge alert-info">{{ request_all_period.count }}</span></td>
    </tr>

  {% else %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ start_date|date:"d/m/Y" }} to {{ end_date|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
      <td>{{ publication_selected }}</td>
      <td>{% trans 'No downloads/No requests' %}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It displays only the last object in my list and I am always inside the `{% else %}` part while I can print statistics for this specific object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use ANNOTATE not AGGREGATE in download_all_period query,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45983784/6348368