# Django annotate queryset by predicate and count results

Tags: python, django, annotations, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


class Score(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name="score", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_score = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    second_score = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    is_rusk = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

And I got a queryset of Game objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 314317035,
        "score": [
            {
                "first_score": 5,
                "second_score": 1,
                "is_rusk": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 311298177,
        "score": [
            {
                "first_score": 5,
                "second_score": 2,
                "is_rusk": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 310278749,
        "score": [
            {
                "first_score": 5,
                "second_score": 2,
                "is_rusk": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 309866238,
        "score": [
            {
                "first_score": 5,
                "second_score": 0,
                "is_rusk": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 307926664,
        "score": [
            {
                "first_score": 5,
                "second_score": 0,
                "is_rusk": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 306047964,
        "score": [
            {
                "first_score": 4,
                "second_score": 5,
                "is_rusk": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 304881611,
        "score": [
            {
                "first_score": 5,
                "second_score": 3,
                "is_rusk": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 304468136,
        "score": [
            {
                "first_score": 5,
                "second_score": 2,
                "is_rusk": false
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I want to annotate this queryset with `rusks_cnt`, it will be count of objects with `is_rusk=True`, If there is a way to not add this to every object, just as one field, that would be good too.

I think easiest way to do it like this:

```
cnt = queryset.filter(score__is_rusk=True).count()
```

But when I'm trying to annotate like this:

```
cnt = queryset.filter(score__is_rusk=True).count()
queryset = queryset.annotate(cnt=cnt)
```

It says:

`QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): 2.`

I've also tried:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
         rusk_cnt=Sum(
                Case(When(score__is_rusk=True, then=1)), output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
```

But results are:

```
[
    {
        "id": 279658929,
        "rusk_cnt": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 279796553,
        "rusk_cnt": null
    },
    ...
]
```

Also I wondering is just using `.count()` will lead to bad performance?

Answer (score 1):

Annotate is for calculating on every entry. If you want to calculate for the entire queryset, use Aggregate.

[Difference between Django's annotate and aggregate methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981837/difference-between-djangos-annotate-and-aggregate-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate with a `Value`:

```
from django.db.models import Value

cnt = queryset.filter(score__is_rusk=True).count()
queryset = queryset.annotate(cnt=Value(cnt))
```

But this will add the *same* value: the number of `Score` objects for the `Game`s in the `queryset` to *all* `Game` objects, which does not make much sense.

If you want to annotate the `Game` objects with `True` the number of objects where `Score` with `is_rusk=True`, you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

queryset.annotate(
    rusk_cnt=Sum('score', filter=Q(score__is_rusk=True))
)
```