# Django South: Combining "alter table"s for better performance?

Tags: mysql, django, django-south

Doing a little digging into why [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) migration was so slow on production data I found that it's doing a separate ALTER TABLE for each column added to the table. In the case of our larger tables they have tens of millions of rows, and I'm adding quite a few columns, so it ends up being very slow.

Is there a way to combine the multiple ALTER TABLE statements South produces into a single statement, and if so would that be faster than several individual statements (I assume it would)?

It looks like [there isn't a way to get South to print the SQL it uses](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/480). Are there any tricks for getting even partial SQL from south? I can hand-assemble the alter table if I can get the individual parts.

Answer (score 0):

South use ORM for own queries, so [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/show-the-sql-django-is-running)

```
./manage.py shell

from django.db import connection
    print connection.queries
```

BUT I'm strongly recommend for hiload/sensitive data solutions using DB console and manually written SQLs ( with full backups of cource )