# django how to see sql query when running tests?

Tags: sql, django, oracle, unit-testing, django-testing

One of my django application unit test fails with

```
DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I would like to see actual SQL query that caused this error. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: Is this helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/show-the-sql-django-is-running

Comment: Not exactly. I don't want to include 'print connection.queries' in the test case because in order to execute that line I would need first to catch an exception. If I catch that exception the test will pass which is not good. Reraising this exception is not very elegant, I'm looking for some better solution.

Comment: Another thing is that 'print' doesn't work with tests - at least for me...

Comment: One way or another you're going to have to catch the exception in order to display any information at the moment of the error.  I don't see anything inelegant with reraising the exception -- just use the `raise` keyword all by itself and it'll pass through with the stack trace intact.

Comment: Oh, actually, I guess there is another solution -- you can log at the DEBUG level and configure your logger to write all SQL queries to the log as they happen.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Comment: In recent versions of cx_Oracle you can set the environment variable DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL to 24 and then run your program, see [Low Level SQL Tracing in cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tracing_sql.html#low-level-sql-tracing-in-cx-oracle). The environment variable values are shown in [ODPI-C Debugging](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/user_guide/debugging.html). Using the value 16+8=24 will give SQL statements & errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found so far is debugsqlshell custom django management command provided by django-debugtoolbar.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to use the `debugsqlshell` command to run a test. That is not explained in the documentation of django-debugtoolbar.

Comment: @gogognome it doesn't I believe mnowotka misunderstood the question. Well, actually, just figured out that he is the TS, so here is -1 for wrong accepted answer

Answer (score 36):

Another option is to use `CaptureQueriesContext` (tested with `pytest`).

```py
from django.db import connection
from django.test.utils import CaptureQueriesContext


def test_foo():
    with CaptureQueriesContext(connection) as ctx:
        # code that runs SQL queries
        print(ctx.captured_queries)
```

Sources:

- https://blog.ploetzli.ch/2019/showing-sql-queries-with-pytest-and-django/
- [How to force django to print each executed sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827250/how-to-force-django-to-print-each-executed-sql-query)

Comment: This is the simplest and cleanest answer as it lets you capture queries for any arbitrarily small section of code, which if you are looking to troubleshoot a problem or optimize queries is what you want.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to print/log *all* SQL queries from the tests, try subclassing `TestCase` like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template import Template, Context
import sys
from django.db import connection
from django.test import TestCase

class LoggingTestCase(TestCase):

  @staticmethod
  def setUpClass():
    # The test runner sets DEBUG to False. Set to True to enable SQL logging.
    settings.DEBUG = True
    super(LoggingTestCase, LoggingTestCase).setUpClass()

  @staticmethod
  def tearDownClass():
    super(LoggingTestCase, LoggingTestCase).tearDownClass()

    time = sum([float(q['time']) for q in connection.queries])
    t = Template("{{count}} quer{{count|pluralize:\"y,ies\"}} in {{time}} seconds:\n\n{% for sql in sqllog %}[{{forloop.counter}}] {{sql.time}}s: {{sql.sql|safe}}{% if not forloop.last %}\n\n{% endif %}{% endfor %}")
    print >> sys.stderr, t.render(Context({'sqllog': connection.queries, 'count': len(connection.queries), 'time': time}))

    # Empty the query list between TestCases.    
    connection.queries = []
```

Then use `LoggingTestCase` instead of `TestCase` as the base class in your tests. Just remember to call this `tearDownClass` if you override it.

Comment: You should call the super setUpClass too. When you don't, things are missing, for example fixture loading.

Comment: @arsenbonbon good point, fixed now. If you downvoted, please consider un-downvoting, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Django really doesn't allow you to set some environment variable to print out all queries?

Comment: [How to override settings for tests.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings)

Answer (score 9):

You can also do the following to get the queries (and then for instance print it or evaluate it in your test).

Actually you [shouldn't alter `django.conf.settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings) nowadays, therefore I use [`override_settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings).

```
from django.db import connection, reset_queries
from django.test import override_settings, TransactionTestCase

class TransactionTests(TransactionTestCase):

    @override_settings(DEBUG=True)
    def test_sql(self):
        reset_queries()
        try:
            # Code that uses the ORM goes here
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        self.assertEqual(connection.queries, [])
```

`TestCase` might also be suitable, see the differences in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44451591/2704544).

See the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) for details for SQL output.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use [`connection.execute_wrapper()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/instrumentation/#connection-execute-wrapper) in your test as follows:

```py
from django.db import connection

def logger(execute, sql, params, many, context):
    print(sql, params)
    return execute(sql, params, many, context)

class GizmoTest(TestCase):

    def test_with_sql_logging(self):
        with connection.execute_wrapper(logger):
            code_that_uses_database()
```

Tested with Django 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

Its not the cleanest solution but if you just quickly want to debug without installing additional packages you could look for the execute() method in django/db.

For **Oracle** I guess it is in:

django/db/backends/oracle/base.py and look for:

```
def execute
```

For **PostgreSQL** it is in:

django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py

In CursorWrapper there is a execute() method.

Both are catching IntegrityError and DatabaseError, you can add a print statement there.

For ppl who want to see all sql queries, put the print statement right after the function call.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `pytest` and `pytest-django` just create a fixture for it

```
@pytest.fixture
def debug_queries(db):
    """ Because pytest run tests with DEBUG=False
        the regular query logging will not work, use this fixture instead
    """
    from django.db import connection
    from django.test.utils import CaptureQueriesContext
    with CaptureQueriesContext(connection):
        yield connection
```

then in your tests

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test__queries(debug_queries):
    # run your queries here
```

of course, your logging config should enable logging of queries, something like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: SQL queries are not printed out.

Comment: This worked for me!
Do you know if it's possible to use the `settings` fixture from `pytest-django` to set the logger for tests? I tried to use it but it did not work for logging in this case.

Comment: @oglop not sure what you mean by `using settings fixture`. What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @EugeneK `pytest-django` has settings fixture that can override the settings https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html?highlight=fixtures#settings
I was thinking that maybe I could use it as an argument for `debug_queries` so I do not need to add logging config in `test.settings.py` and just use the fixture if needed.

Comment: @oglop
you can always set logger level to DEBUG inside the `debug_queries` fixture, no need to hack settings. Don't forget to restore the level when the fixture exits

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution which worked for me (Django 3.1):

```py
from django.test import TestCase


class TestSomething(TestCase):
    @override_settings(DEBUG=True)
    def test_something(self):
        pass
    
    def tearDown(self):
        from django.db import connection
        for query in connection.queries:
            print(f"✅ {query['sql']}\n")
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/graffic/4873112c02914f5f8717296bcbf8d86a)

Answer (score 0):

You can change console level to DEBUG in settings.  It worked on Django 1.9.

```
LOGGING = {
...
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Does not work "For performance reasons, SQL logging is only enabled when settings.DEBUG is set to True, regardless of the logging level or handlers that are installed." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#django-db-backends

Answer (score 0):

All the options here were too complicated/and too many things could go wrong. This works on `django` >= `1.11+` <= `4.x` [tested it on the `main` branch] (until they break it in the future..)

It works by ignoring `settings.DEBUG` entirely and just injecting the `CursorDebugWrapper` to be used always, thus logging the SQLs that ran.

```
import inspect
from collections import deque
from contextlib import contextmanager
from unittest import mock

from django.db import connections
from django.db.backends import utils


@contextmanager
def print_queries(using="default"):
    """
    [debug] Prints out all the queries in real time

    To avoid messing with django's logging and get the SQL working inside
    tests where `DEBUG` can be set to `False`, this bypasses all that and
    goes straight for the kill.

    Example:

        class TestSomething(TestCase):
            def test_something(self):
                with print_queries():
                    Model.objects.create(a=1, b=2)

        def test_something():
            with print_queries():
                Model.objects.create(a=1, b=2)

    """

    def fake_maker(self, cursor):
        """
        Normally `make_cursor` uses `CursorWrapper` which does NOT debug.
        """
        return utils.CursorDebugWrapper(cursor, self)

    class Snitch(deque):
        """
        Modified version of `deque` that `print()`s out all the items inserted to it.
        """

        def append(self, item):
            current_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
            while True:
                info = inspect.getframeinfo(current_frame)
                if "/django/" in info.filename:
                    current_frame = current_frame.f_back
                    continue
                break

            print("*", item["sql"], item["time"], f"{info.filename}:{info.lineno}")
            return super().append(item)

    connection_ = connections[using]
    mock_maker = mock.patch("django.db.backends.base.base.BaseDatabaseWrapper.make_cursor", fake_maker)
    mock_deque = mock.patch.object(connection_, "queries_log", Snitch(maxlen=connection_.queries_log.maxlen))

    with mock_maker, mock_deque:
        yield
```

Use it like this:

```
def test_whatever():
    ...
    with print_queries():
        Model.objects.create(a=1, b=2)  # any query here
    ...
```

Output looks like:

```
* SELECT .. FROM "table" WHERE ... 0.001 /full/path/file.py:136
* SELECT .. FROM "table" WHERE ... 0.001 /full/path/file.py:245
```

Will tell you where in your code the query is being made.

Answer (score 0):

I combined a couple of existing answers into a utility function I've found handy to have when debugging individual tests:

```py
import traceback
from django.db import connections

@contextmanager
def log_queries():
    """
    Prints queries and their tracebacks when they are executed.

    Usage:
    
        with log_queries():
            do_something_with_the_database()
    """

    db = connections["default"]

    def print_stack_in_project(
        execute, sql, params, many, context
    ):
        try:
            return execute(sql, params, many, context)
        finally:
            query = db.queries_log[-1]
            print(f"[{query['time']}] {query['sql']}")
            traceback.print_stack()
            print()  # to separate stacks

    with db.execute_wrapper(print_stack_in_project):
        yield
```

Comment: For completeness of solutions, one quick way to check the SQL being executed  in cx_Oracle and python-oracledb Thick mode is to set the environment variable DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL to 16 before running the app, see [Low Level SQL Tracing](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tracing.html#low-level-sql-tracing).  This won't give the values of bind variables nor give the Python stack.