# Difference between TestCase and TransactionTestCase classes in django test

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-testing

Please explain the difference between the `TestCase` class and `TransactionTestCase` class. I have read the documentation but it's only saying that `TestCase` runs tests in a database transaction and uses rollback to "undo" the test in the database, and if you need to manually manage transactions within your test, you would need to use `django.test.TransactionTestCase`.

Please help me understand the actual difference with an example.
In what condition will `TestCase` fail? Do rollbacks happen automatically or do we have to write code to do the rollback?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The main difference between `TestCase` and `TransactionTestCase` is that `TestCase` wraps the tests with `atomic()` blocks ALL THE TIME. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#testcase):

> Wraps the tests within two nested atomic() blocks: one for the whole class and one for each test

Now imagine that you have a method that should raise an error if it is not wrapped inside `atomic()` block. You are trying to write a test for that:

```
def test_your_method_raises_error_without_atomic_block(self):
    with self.assertRaises(SomeError):
        your_method()
```

This test will unexpectedly fail! The reason is, you guessed it, `TestCase` wraps the tests with `atomic()` blocks ALL THE TIME. Thus, `your_method()` will not raise an error, which is why this test will fail. In this case, you should use TransactionTestCase to make your test pass.

[select_for_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_for_update) is a clear case in point:

> Evaluating a queryset with select_for_update() in autocommit mode on backends which support SELECT ... FOR UPDATE is a TransactionManagementError error

From the [TransactionTestCase documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase):

> with TestCase class, you cannot test that a block of code is executing within a transaction, as is required when using select_for_update()

And if we take a look at the documentation of `select_for_update()`, we see a warning:

> Although select_for_update() normally fails in autocommit mode, since TestCase automatically wraps each test in a transaction, calling select_for_update() in a TestCase even outside an atomic() block will (perhaps unexpectedly) pass without raising a TransactionManagementError. To properly test select_for_update() you should use TransactionTestCase.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

I would like to post some example and django code here so that you can know how `TransactionTestCase` and `TestCase` work.

Both `TransactionTestCase` and `TestCase` are inherit from `SimpleTestCase`. Difference:

- When runing the test, `TestCase` will check if the current DB support transaction feature. If true, a transaction will be created and all test code are now under a "transaction block". And at the end of the test, `TestCase` will rollback all things to keep your DB clean. Read the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` functions below:

  ```
   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
           super(TestCase, cls).setUpClass()
           if not connections_support_transactions():
               return
           cls.cls_atomics = cls._enter_atomics()

           if cls.fixtures:
               for db_name in cls._databases_names(include_mirrors=False):
                       try:
                           call_command('loaddata', *cls.fixtures, **{
                               'verbosity': 0,
                               'commit': False,
                               'database': db_name,
                           })
                       except Exception:
                           cls._rollback_atomics(cls.cls_atomics)
                           raise
           cls.setUpTestData()


   @classmethod
   def tearDownClass(cls):
       if connections_support_transactions():
           cls._rollback_atomics(cls.cls_atomics)
           for conn in connections.all():
               conn.close()
       super(TestCase, cls).tearDownClass()
  ```
- `TransactionTestCase`, however, does not start a transaction. It simply flushes the DB after all tests done.

  ```
   def _post_teardown(self):
       try:
           self._fixture_teardown()
           super(TransactionTestCase, self)._post_teardown()
           if self._should_reload_connections():
               for conn in connections.all():
                   conn.close()
       finally:
           if self.available_apps is not None:
               apps.unset_available_apps()
               setting_changed.send(sender=settings._wrapped.__class__,
                                    setting='INSTALLED_APPS',
                                    value=settings.INSTALLED_APPS,
                                    enter=False)

   def _fixture_teardown(self):
       for db_name in self._databases_names(include_mirrors=False):
           call_command('flush', verbosity=0, interactive=False,
                        database=db_name, reset_sequences=False,
                        allow_cascade=self.available_apps is not None,
                        inhibit_post_migrate=self.available_apps is not None)
  ```

Now some very simple example using `select_for_update()` mentioned in official docs:

```
    class SampleTestCase(TestCase):
            def setUp(self):
                Sample.objects.create(**{'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'})

            def test_difference_testcase(self):
                sample = Sample.objects.select_for_update().filter()
                print(sample)


    class SampleTransactionTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            Sample.objects.create(**{'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'})

        def test_difference_transactiontestcase(self):
            sample = Sample.objects.select_for_update().filter()
            print(sample)
```

The first one will raise:

> AssertionError: TransactionManagementError not raised

And the second one will pass without an error.