# Why did the Django model return an empty queryset in the thread pool?

Tags: python, multithreading, django-rest-framework, threadpool, django-tests

I used ThreadPoolExecutor in my API. in the test case, I generated a Movie instance and saved it in the database (PostgreSQL). I printed movie count in the test case, API, and thread pool function. why in the thread pool return an empty queryset?

**view.py:**

```
def movie_count():
   print(Movie.objects.count(), "movie count in the thread")


class MovieListView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (
       render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer,
       renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer,
    ) 

   def get(self, request, key, format=None):

      print(Movie.objects.count(), "movie count before the thread")

      with ThreadPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
          bookmarked_future = executor.submit(movie_count)
          bookmarked_future.result()

    return Response({})
```

**test.py**

```
def test_mock_function(self):
    Movie.objects.create(
        title="Title"
    )
    print(Movie.objects.count(), "movie count in the test")

    url = reverse('video_api:list', args=('tops',))
    self.client.get(url, format='json', data={'limit': 30})
```

result:

```
1 movie counts in the test
1 movie count before the thread
0 movie count in the thread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

[Difference between TestCase and TransactionTestCase classes in django test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450533/difference-between-testcase-and-transactiontestcase-classes-in-django-test)

> the APITestCase wraps the tests with 2 atomic() blocks, one for the
> whole test class and one for each test within the class. This
> essentially stops tests from altering the database for other tests as
> the transactions are rolled back at the end of each test. By having
> this second atomic() block around the whole test class, specific
> database transaction behaviour can be hard to test and hence you'd
> want to drop back to using APITransactionTestCase.