# Foreign Key Relationships

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=COURSE_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField('created', auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField('modified', auto_now=True)
    syllabus = models.FileField(upload_to='syllabus')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and

```
class Pastquestion(models.Model):
    subject=models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    year =models.PositiveIntegerField()
    questions = models.FileField(upload_to='pastquestions')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.year)
```

Each Subject can have one or more past questions but a past question can have only one subject. I want to get a subject, and get its related past questions of a particular `year`. I was thinking of fetching a subject and getting its related past question.

Currently am implementing my code such that I rather get the past question whose subject and year correspond to any specified subject like

```
this_subject=Subject.objects.get(name=the_subject)
thepastQ=Pastquestion.objects.get(year=2000,subject=this_subject)
```

I was thinking there is a better way to do this. Or is this already a better way? Please Do tell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the `related_name` property of the `ForeignKey` field. This creates a link back to the `Subject` object and provides a manager you can use to query the set.

So to use this functionality, change the foreignkey line to:

```
subject=models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='questions')
```

Then with an instance of `Subject` we'll call `subj`, you can:

```
subj.questions.filter(year=2000)
```

I don't think this performs much differently to the technique you have used. Roughly speaking, SQL performance boils down a) whether there's an index and b) how many queries you're issuing. So you need to think about both. One way to find out what SQL your model usage is generating is to use [SqlLogMiddleware](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/61/) - and alternatively play with the options in [How to show the SQL Django is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/show-the-sql-django-is-running) It can be tempting when you get going to start issuing queries across relationships - e.g. `q = Question.objects.get(year=2000, subject__name=SUBJ_MATHS)` but unless you keep a close eye on these types of queries, you can and will kill your app's performance, badly.

Answer (score 0):

Django's query syntax allows you to ['reach into](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)' related objects.

```
past_questions = Pastquestion.objects.filter(year=2000, subject__name=subject_name)
```

Comment: @Æsahættr answer is also a good one. If the context of your problem requires you to have the Subject object anyway, that would be a more efficient method.