# Django Models Create a Coustom Query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-permissions

I am trying to get all the post in a thread before or on a certain time. So how do I get Django to allow me the privilege to enter my own queries?

This is the closest I could come using Django's model functions.

```
# need to get all the post from Thread post_set that were created before Thread post_set 9
posts = Thread.post_set.filter(created <= Thread.post_set.all()[9].created)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) like so:

```
Thread.objects.raw('SELECT ... FROM myapp_thread WHERE ...')
```

Comment: Thanks `raw` was what I was looking for. Also is there a way to look at the queries the filter uses? Or a  site that translates what the filter does. i.e. `created_lt`, `id__exact`

Comment: Just `print post.query`, replace `post` with the name of your query object.

Comment: @Crispy See this answer for information on it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1074224/1888559

Answer (score 2):

If `post_set` is a foreign key,  then use:

```
posts = Thread.objects.filter( post_set__created__lt=datetime.date(2013, 5, 10))
```

If you still want to go with a raw SQL query, as detailed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), please be careful, as **no escaping is automatically performed**.