# How to output SQL generated by Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-orm

How do you output the SQL that Django's admin is generating to query results for the dhangelist pages? I tried overriding `queryset()` via:

```
def queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    print 'sql:',qs.query
    return qs
```

but even though I'm browsing `/admin/myapp/mymodel/?segment=123&date=2012-1-1`, this is showing the query:

```
sql: SELECT myapp_mymodel.id, myapp_mymodel.segment, myapp_mymodel.start_date
FROM myapp_mymodel ORDER BY myapp_mymodel.start_date ASC
```

Notice the complete lack of any filters I specified in my URL.

I'm trying to debug a weird problem where if I manually query the table in SQL, I see one result, but Django's admin is showing something completely different. I suspect there's a bug in Django that's causing incorrect SQL to be generated, but I need to see the SQL to confirm that that's the problem.

I'm using Django 1.5.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply set in settings.py this logging configuration to have all SQL queries printed on the console

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        },
    }
}
```

This is the part responsible for printing

```
       'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        },
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the debug_toolbar: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar

Check it out. It's worth it.

Comment: Wow, that's really nifty. It does show a query that includes the filters. Unfortunately, when I run that query, I get a result that still doesn't match my admin. Very puzzling. The only other thing I can think of is admin is caching an old query, but I have all caching disabled...