# Optimized Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following function to determine who downloaded a certain book:

```
@cached_property
def get_downloader_info(self):
    return self.downloaders.select_related('user').values(
        'user__username', 'user__full_name')
```

Since I'm only using two fields, does it make sense to use `.defer()` on the remaining fields?

I tried to use `.only()`, but I get an error that some fields are not JSON serializable.

I'm open to all suggestions, if any, for optimizing this queryset.

Thank you!

Comment: did you inspect the query that is generated ? Example: `self.downloaders.select_related('user').values(
        'user__username', 'user__full_name').query` you can analyze that to see if it is really worth optimizing any further

Comment: @karthikr Where would I find the output to see if it should be optimized?

Comment: what database backend are you using?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you try every possible optimization, you should get your hands on the SQL query generated by the ORM (you can [print it to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/show-the-sql-django-is-running) or use something like [django debug toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.4/)) and see what is slow about it. After that I suggest you run that query with [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html) and find out what is slow about that query. If the query is slow because lot of data has to be transfer than it makes lot of sense to use `only` or `defer`. Using `only` and `defer` (or `values`) gives you better performances only if you need to retrieve lot of data, but it does not make your database job much easier (unless you really have to read a lot of data of course).

Since you are using Django and Postgresql, you can get a psql session with `manage.py dbshell` and get query timings with `\timing`

Comment: Even if it only helped a little bit, wouldn't it make sense to optimize every aspect possible? I just installed the Django Debug Toolbar though, so thank you.