# In Django How determine or log the num of db calls in one view?

Tags: django, python-3.x

How i can determine the number of calls does by my app in one view call.
I intent to make a decorator with this intention.

```
@trace_db_calls
def my_view(request):
     #code
     return HttpResponse('done')
```

At this moment I am investigating how to do it, regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show the SQL Django is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-to-show-the-sql-django-is-running)

Answer (score 0):

you should look at the [django-debug-tool](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar). You can open the django debug shell with command `python manage.py debugsqlshell` and in shell you can call your function. It'll show all the database queries made.

Also if you are looking for a way to log SQL queries in a file you can look at this middleware. Middleware runs on every request.

- https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/264/
- https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/290/

Comment: The `debugsqlshell` does not appear to exist anymore