# Django, is there a way to see what SQL queries are being executed?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datatable, django-queryset

I'm exploring https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable, it looks nice but Im wondering if it will query the whole data or query the paginated data. This information is highly needed to determine performance.

I would like to know in Django, is there a way to see what is the underlying queries is being executed ?

Im using Django==1.11.7

Comment: Django is lazy query and still  lazy after got data. Like i did with datatable, the search function (in search bar) will re-use the data object to filter again

Comment: Thanks, are you saying with datatable is loads all data ? not the paginated ones ?

Comment: what is a good way to solve this ? do a separate search then right ?

Comment: def get_initial_queryset(self): just define the STANDER query, each page/search will add an option of filter to this query ~> each time, datatable reload, it will query again. You can check it in: def filter_queryset(self, qs):  Let print like:  print("QS - raw:", qs.query) and you will see it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

Comment: cezar, thank you. this is what im looking for!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see the actual SQL generated by Django's ORM, you can print out the `.query` attribute of a queryset. Here's an example with an app called `home` and model called `Question` that I generated in the Django shell:

```
 $ python manage.py shell
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from home.models import Question
>>> q = Question.objects.all()
>>> print(q.query)
SELECT "home_question"."id", "home_question"."date_added", "home_question"."question", "home_question"."number_of_answers" FROM "home_question"
```

Looking at the methods of `django-datatable`, it looks like the filtered and paginated views are based on filtering the results of `get_queryset`, which returns `model.objects.all()`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    model = TableDataMap.get_model(self.token)
    if model is None:
        return None
    return model.objects.all()
```

Comment: Documentation can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running

Comment: thank you. as datatable is my interest of investigation, how did you know of that function get_queryset ? does it mean it returns all ? and then let javascript to do the filtered result ?

Comment: @Axil the `FeedDataView` class subclasses [BaseListView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.4/django.views.generic.list/BaseListView/), so the `get_queryset` method here overrides the one it inherits. But in this case I think it does simply return all objects.

Comment: @StuartDines thanks, I cant get that working though https://imgur.com/a/gKr3Q DEBUG = True in settings.py is

Answer (score 3):

Another way to see all the queries that have been performed.

```
python manage.py shell
>> from django.db import connection
>> from app.models import SomeModel
>> obj = SomeModel.objects.first()
>> connection.queries
>> <Returns a list of all the queries that have been executed in the session upto this point>
```

This also allows you to see how many queries have been performed

Comment: When you use it in a test use `@override_settings(DEBUG=True)`