# Django prefetch related and exists

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I am using `prefetch_related` when querying a model that have several m2m relationships:

```
qs = context.mymodel_set.prefetch_related('things1', 'things2', 'things3')
```

So that when I do this there is no need to perform an additional query to get `things1`, they should have been fetched already:

```
r = list(qs)
r[0].things1.all()
```

But what if I do `r[0].things1.exists()`? Will this generate a new query? Or will it use the prefetched information? If it generates a new query, does that mean that going for `r[0].things1.all()` for the purposes of existence checking is more efficient?

PS: cached information being in desync with the database does not worry me for this particular question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to [check the queries that Django is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) for yourself.

When I tried it, it appeared that `obj.things.exists()` did not cause any additional queries when `things` was prefetched.

Comment: I am testing this with `shell_plus --print-sql` and `r[0].things1.all()` seems to be querying the db. But when I do `r[0].things1.exists()` nothing is printed out.

Comment: It looks like I was wrong - it appears that `exists()` does not cause an additional query when the `things` has been prefetched. Your `r[0].things.all()` should not cause any additional queries - that's the point of prefetching. You haven't shown what the queries are -- perhaps your `__str__` method causes foreign key lookups.

Answer (score -1):

To capture only objects having relation with `things1` it can go in the query like this:

```
context.mymodel_set.prefetch_related(
   'things1', 'things2', 'things3'
).filter(
    things1__isnull=False
)
```