# Conditionally Filter Within Django Queryset

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering if there is a way to conditionally filter a queryset in Django based on if the value filtered against is `None` or not. I know that you can do something like this:

```
some_name = 'Bob'
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(gender='boy')
if some_name:
    qs = qs.filter(name=some_name)
```

where we conditionally filter on the variable `some_name` only if it exists. I'm curious if this logic can be replicated with a single query statement, instead of "chaining" on a filter to the end of a queryset. So this would look something like:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(gender='boy').filter(name=some_name if some_name else None)
```

Obviously that example isn't valid, because it would filter on name=None instead of not filtering, but has anyone found a way to do what I'm intending? For longer, nested queries, it would be very helpful to have it all in one statement.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a built-in way to do this in Django specifically, but you can make use of the dictionary unpack operator `**` and a dictionary comprehension to achieve the desired result.

For example:

```
some_name = 'Bob'
field_value_pairs = [('gender', 'boy'), ('name', some_name)]
filter_options = {k:v for k,v in field_value_pairs if v}
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(**filter_options)
```

So if `some_name` is `None`, then the `'name'` field will be excluded from `filter_options` and therefore not be included in the filter query.

---

Update:

You can also use the [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to build a query that can be passed to a single call of the `filter` method. This allows for more flexibility and allows for more complex filtering similar to the SQL `WHERE` clause.

For example:

```
from django.db.models import Q

some_name = 'Bob'
query = Q(gender='boy')
if some_name:
    query = query & Q(name=some_name)
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(query)
```

Or if you want a more compact view for simple cases like this:

```
query = Q(gender='boy') & (Q(name=some_name) if some_name else Q())
```

or (closer to your desired look):

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(gender='boy') & (Q(name=some_name) if some_name else Q()))
```

Note that using separate `filter` calls isn't really bad since only one database query will be made (assuming you don't try to reference the objects in the query set before the last `filter` call). You can check this by [looking at the database queries Django is making](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running). But as a matter of style, I can see the preference for only calling `filter` once.