# django last_executed_query: what is the purporse of the sql, params paremeters passed in the function

Tags: django, postgresql

I am working on a Django project and using Postgresql as database.

I wanted to know what does `sql, params` do in the below function which i found at `/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/operations.py`

```
def last_executed_query(self, cursor, sql, params):
    # http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.query
    # The query attribute is a Psycopg extension to the DB API 2.0.
    if cursor.query is not None:
        return cursor.query.decode()
    return None
```

I found it being used at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47542953/2897115

```
def str_query(qs):
    """
    qs.query returns something that isn't valid SQL, this returns the actual
    valid SQL that's executed: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17741
    """
    cursor = connections[qs.db].cursor()
    query, params = qs.query.sql_with_params()
    cursor.execute('EXPLAIN ' + query, params)
    res = str(cursor.db.ops.last_executed_query(cursor, query, params))
    assert res.startswith('EXPLAIN ')
    return res[len('EXPLAIN '):]
```

Since `(sql, params)` or here `(query, params)` are not being used then `last_executed_query` return the same as `connections[qs.db][queries][-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other backends [do use sql and params](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py#L145). You can only use `connection.queries` in debug mode.