# How to get sql equivalent query from django query?

Tags: django, django-models

Currently I am developing website in Django & I need to convert some djnago query to sql equivalent query.

```
Purchase_order.objects.filter(query).order_by(id)[start: (start+length)]
```

I want to convert above django query into sql type of query.

Is there any way availble to convert it into sql also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  *django* does *provides* that feature. `queryset` comes with `query` object.

```
purchase_order = Purchase_order.objects.filter(query).order_by(id)[start: (start+length)]  

print(purchase_order.query)
```

---

this will print corresponding query.