# How can i see a raw sql command in django?

Tags: django

I have see some code of everybody on here. But it's still difficult, and lost a ton of time. Have some way to do this ? Thank you, love all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use :

> python manage.py sqlmigrate (name_your_app)(your_number_at_migrations_folder)
>
> Ex: python manage.py sqlmigrate blog 0001

Answer (score 0):

You can use `django.db.backends` log to log the sql queries. Set this on your settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```