# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm working on a Django application with MySQL version 8.0. I changed to version 5.7 after I running my application I'm getting this error "sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by ovr.obj_nm)" but the details are storing in DB normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the actual sql query that is being executed using `query` method on a `QuerySet` object. More on how to do it in this stack answer: [How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

Comment: Is any sql version problem is causing this error ?because i didnt see this error when im running in server version 8.0.After  i changed my server version to 5.7 then only I got this error.

Comment: Also check python version against the django version and the mysql version. Apparently this could be a problem as well. Let me know how it goes, good luck!

Comment: The problem is after i changed my mysql server version to 5.7 im getting this error . but the same application has been working well in mysql server version 8. so version is the problem.