# Django with MongoDB without using ORM

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mongodb, nosql

I want to do CRUD app with authorization using DJango and MongoDB without using ORM. How can I implement this in my project and do it with some buttons on my page?

Now im using DJongo but i wont using ORM.

I have no idea how to do it.

For example - after click button you will add or delete something to database without using ORM.

Comment: how do you expect to read object without ORM ? like executing MongoDB queries directly ? `SELECT * FROM model` ?? and why do you want to do that

Comment: I found some exercise like this, yes something like this ```SELECT * FROM model``` but for mongoDB something like this ```db.bios.findOne(
    { },
    { name: 1, contribs: 1 }
)```

Comment: i am not an expert in mongoDB but you can do `model.objects.all().query()` and it will give you the query that have been executed and Install PyMongo and use it ... still i don't know why you don't want use the defauld django query set

Comment: this is a way to get the query [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) ||| this alsow might help[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

Comment: you can use queries directly (high speed without orm) , use pymongo , this link help you https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html