# How to print sql query from Django as Debug is False

Tags: django

From doc [how can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/faq/models/)

I can get sql executed by:

```
from django.db import connection
connection.queries
```

But it's only available while `Debug == True`

How to print sql as `Debug == False`?

Thanks

> Update

I want something like this:

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db import reset_queries

reset_queries()  # Clears the query.
with transaction.atomic():
    r = Amodel.objects.create(
        ...
    )

    Bmodel.objects.filter(id__in=handle_ids_).update(status=4)

# Prints the sql executed in this transaction block.
logger.info("[sql_execute]: {}".format(connection.queries))
```

Comment: do you want to see all queries or only some particular?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work with [Database instrumentation [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/instrumentation/) which basically provides a hook for installing wrapper functions around the execution of database queries. Using this you can simply make a wrapper like so:

```
class QueryLogger:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queries = []
        self.errored = False

    def __call__(self, execute, sql, params, many, context):
        current_query = {'sql': sql, 'params': params, 'many': many}
        try:
            result = execute(sql, params, many, context)
        except Exception as e:
            self.errored = True
            current_query['status'] = 'error'
            current_query['exception'] = e
            raise
        else:
            current_query['status'] = 'ok'
            return result
        finally:
            self.queries.append(current_query)
```

Then use it in your view:

```
from django.db import connection


ql = QueryLogger()

with connection.execute_wrapper(ql), transaction.atomic():
    r = Amodel.objects.create(
        ...
    )
    Bmodel.objects.filter(id__in=handle_ids_).update(status=4)

if not ql.errored:
    for query in ql.queries:
        print(query)
else:
    print("Some error occured")
```