# Django ORM can't execute it's own raw query

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I use Django with Postgres as my database.

If I run this code:

```
SomeClass.objects.filter(text__regex=rf"searchkeyword")
the_query = str(SomeClass.query)
```

The `the_query` variable will be this:

```
SELECT * FROM "SomeClass" WHERE "SomeClass "."text"::text ~ searchkeyword
```

But when you run this query using `SomeClass.objects.raw(query)`, it will show this error:

```
Exception Value:    
column "usa" does not exist
... WHERE "SomeClass"."text"::text ~* searchkeyword
```

So, basically, Django ORM can't run the raw query that it made itself.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

**First Edit**:
Even for simpler queries like this, I get the same error:

```
SomeClass.objects.filter(text="searchkeyword")

column "searchkeyword" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM SomeClass WHERE text = searchkeyword
```

**Second Edit**:
This is a little different question than this:
[Printing Django QuerySet SQL with ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112554/printing-django-queryset-sql-with)

In my case, even it does not work if double quotations are used and not removed.

Comment: Note that `.query` is not really part of the public API, you shouldn't really be using it except for pickling / unpickling queries as described in the documentation

Comment: It looks like your model is not in sync with the database, so you forgot to make migrations and migrate...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that question and it's answers and your second comment here helped me to get some good insight about the root cause of this problem. But, still I am not sure how to solve this problem. If I am not supposed to use `.query` to get the raw query, how should I do it? My scenario: on first page, people can search for a text and I show the result in the second page. In second page, I have a download button to let people download the result of query of the previous page. I can't come up with a better solution other than passing this query using a session variable between views.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I checked it. There is no migration issue and it is up to date.

Comment: @MehrdadSalimi see: [How to print sql query from Django as Debug is False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683964/how-to-print-sql-query-from-django-as-debug-is-false)