# What is the performance difference in the following two cases of select_related

Tags: django-views, django-select-related

I have the following two cases. Of the two, I am not able to tell which is the best order to take. Is there a performance issue in either of them??

Case 1

```
Model.objects.filter(item1=4,item2=5).select_related('store').get(id=1)
```

Case 2

```
Model.objects.select_related('store').filter(item1=4,item2=5).get(id=1)
```

Comment: No, both will make exactly the same query.

Comment: Why do you expect a difference?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. I just thought the order mattered.

Comment: @fakeMake: not in this case: a `.select_related('...')` is pushed to the list of items to select when making the query. So both will make a `JOIN` on the `store` and fetch the data of the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the query that Django makes by looking at the [`connections.queries` list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074224/67579). So you can print the last query with:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> print(connection.queries[-1]['sql'])
```

For the first query, we get:

```
>>> Model.objects.filter(item1=4,item2=5).select_related('store').get(id=1)
<Model: Model object (1)>
>>> print(connection.queries[-1]['sql'])
SELECT "app_name_model"."id", "app_name_model"."store_id", "app_name_model"."item1", "app_name_model"."item2", "app_name_store"."id" FROM "app_name_model" INNER JOIN "app_name_store" ON ("app_name_model"."store_id" = "app_name_store"."id") WHERE ("app_name_model"."item1" = 4 AND "app_name_model"."item2" = 5 AND "app_name_model"."id" = 1) LIMIT 21
```

whereas for the latter, it is:

```
>>> Model.objects.select_related('store').filter(item1=4,item2=5).get(id=1)
<Model: Model object (1)>
>>> print(connection.queries[-1]['sql'])
SELECT "app_name_model"."id", "app_name_model"."store_id", "app_name_model"."item1", "app_name_model"."item2", "app_name_store"."id" FROM "app_name_model" INNER JOIN "app_name_store" ON ("app_name_model"."store_id" = "app_name_store"."id") WHERE ("app_name_model"."item1" = 4 AND "app_name_model"."item2" = 5 AND "app_name_model"."id" = 1) LIMIT 21
```

Both produce thus *exactly* the same query:

```
SELECT "app_name_model"."id", "app_name_model"."store_id", "app_name_model"."item1", "app_name_model"."item2",
       "app_name_store"."id"
FROM "app_name_model"
INNER JOIN "app_name_store" ON ("app_name_model"."store_id" = "app_name_store"."id")
WHERE ("app_name_model"."item1" = 4 AND "app_name_model"."item2" = 5 AND "app_name_model"."id" = 1)
```

Where the parts in boldface is the effect of the [**`.select_related(…)`** call <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).