# Django Order_by Retrieves same data thrice

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a model called as Annual. When I am retrieving the annual report from database after using order_by on queryset same data is retrieved thrice.

Here's my views.py

```
class AnnualView(APIView):
    serializer_class = AnnualSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Annual.objects.all().order_by('-group__student__level', '-group__gName')
        print(queryset)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        for serialized_data in serializer.data:
            current = serialized_data.get('current')
            for data in current:
                data.get('topic')['current']= data.get('current')
                data.get('category')['topic']= data.get('topic')
            
                data.pop('topic')
                data.pop('current')
        
        context = {
            "Status": 200,
            "payload": serializer.data
        }

        return Response(context)
```

Here's my Model.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Students, related_name="student_groups", default="No Student")
    gName = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="GroupTeacher", on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    speciality = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSpeciality, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True)

class AnnualCurrentPL(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    current = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    annual = models.ForeignKey("Annual", on_delete=DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

# Annual Report Model
class Annual(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="2022")
    # current = models.CharField(max_length=512, default="current")
    current = models.ManyToManyField(AnnualCurrentPL, related_name="AnnualCurrentPL", blank=True)
    expectations = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
    month = models.ManyToManyField("MonthAnnual", blank=True)

class MonthAnnual(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    numeric_Month = models.IntegerField()
    month = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    goal = models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

I have included all models responsible for end result.

When I disable the order_by from queryset in views.py data is retrieved normally. Have spend hours to figure it out. Only solution I found is to not include order_by in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order_by is causing an implicit join on many tables, including at least one M2M relationship. Your ordering will result at the very least in an entry per student/group/annual relationship. If you do a `print(queryset.values("id", "group__student__level", "group__gName"))`, you'll be able to observe exactly what's happening. You must either use `.distinct()` to grab only the first annual for each entry, or some sort of `.aggregate()`. The [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets) has good examples of both.

And you can always use [`queryset.query`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235636/4728007) to see what the SQL looks like in the future, which is a good starting place for debugging your queries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion using `.distinct()` has solved my issue.