# Does Django model queries automatically make requests for foreign key reference objects?

Tags: python, django

Consider the following Django model:

```
class Name(models.Model):
    pkid      = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    person    = models.ForeignKey(to=Person,
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Will the following query automatically also do a join and retrieve the connected `Person` object, too?

```
results = models.Name.objects.all()
```

Or are all foreign key reference fields in Django automatically deferred until they are accessed?

```
print(results[0].person)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not by default query foreign models when retrieving an instance, however this can be configured using the [`select_related` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). Instead, the foreign instances are queried when referenced (e.g. when `results[0].person` is evaluated).

If you want to explore how Django queries the database, you can view `django.db.connection.queries` (as explained in [How to see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1074212/8068625)).

For example:

First import:

```
from django.db import connection
```

Default functionality:

```
print("queries: ", len(connection.queries)) # 0
results = models.Name.objects.all()
print("queries: ", len(connection.queries)) # 1
print(results[0].person)
print("queries: ", len(connection.queries)) # 2
```

With `select_related`:

```
print("queries: ", len(connection.queries)) # 0
results = models.Name.objects.select_related("person").all()
print("queries: ", len(connection.queries)) # 1
print(results[0].person)
print("queries: ", len(connection.queries)) # 1
```