# Django ORM takes more time than hitting SQL Server with SqlEngine

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, orm, django-queryset, django-serializer

I have a django rest application under development. I am trying to follow the best practices while creating it and thus I have included the models and serializers and using those to access the data.

When trying to access the data for longer period, about a month or so, the API takes more time(x6 times more than for a single day) but the data is not actually high(around 4k rows).

I was thinking the cause maybe location of VMs of SQL and API but when I used sqlEngine and pd.read_sql to connect and retrieve the data for about a month I was able to do so in around 2 secs.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib

conn_str = "<db-connection-string>"
conn_uri = f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_str)}"

sql_engine = sa.create_engine(conn_uri, fast_executemany=False, echo=True)

sql = "select * from <table_name> where <condition>"
df = pd.read_sql(sa.text(sql), sqlEngine.connect())
```

[image]

To check the cause I firstly fetched from queryset directly using `queryset.values_list()` and  later through serializer using `serializer(queryset, many=True)`.
I used **django-debug-toolbar**, the sql query execution is around 200 ms in both cases.

The main time consumed is taking place in highlighted sections:

- Using queryset only(~13 secs)

> .venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models/query.py in _fetch_all(1322)

- Using serializer(~14 secs)

> .venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework/serializers.py in to_representation(678)

I know `to_representation()` method does loop over each field and column to assign the python native datatype, but that's being done for all DBs not just MS SQL Server, so whey does this takes so much time and when I do the same via **SqlLite**(on local) it's more than 20 times faster.

Database in Use: **Microsoft SQL Server**

**EDITED**

Image indicating the number of queries being hit(highlighted the time consumed by SQL and total time until json is retrieved)

[image]

And since this was a test of data retrieval only, no additional work is being performed.

```
from apis import models, serializers
from apis.utils.common_utils import get_dataframe_from_serializer
class TestConnection(APIView):
"""Test DB Connection"""

@logging_func(logger=logger)
def get(self, request, use):
    """create DB connection and test get data"""


    start_date = '2023-08-01'
    end_date = '2023-08-31'
    _id = 'id_value'
    sql = f"""select * from <table> where id='{_id}'""" # query I want to hit
    
    start_time = pd.to_datetime('now')
    m = models.my_model.objects.filter(_id=enterprise_id)
    ser = serializers.my_serializer(m, many=True)
    df = get_dataframe_from_serializer(ser)
    end_time = pd.to_datetime('now')
  
    total_seconds = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()
    return Response(
        {'total_seconds': total_seconds,
         'start_date': start_date,
         'end_date': end_date,
         'rows_retrieved': len(df)
         }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Utility function definition `get_dataframe_from_serializer`

```
def get_dataframe_from_serializer(serializer: object) -> pd.DataFrame:
"""
Return a dataframe of serializer object
no matter if data is present or not, columns are required
"""
# serializers contains a fields attribute which essentially are the columns
# check if fields exist in serializer itself otherwise get it is inside the child instance
if 'fields' in dir(serializer):
    columns = [f for f in serializer.fields]
else:
    columns = [f for f in serializer.child.fields]
# create dataframe from serializer's data and using the columns created above
df = pd.DataFrame(serializer.data, columns=columns)

return df
```

Comment: Likely there is an N+1 problem involved, but without any details regarding the query(set), it is hard to tell...

Comment: Look at the raw queries emitted by django with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70105819/20712

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if it would be N+1 problem wouldn't this also persist when I used SqlLite DB? Also, the model is not related to any other model as I created a copy to test the data fetch and turns out it was itself time consuming.

Comment: @RossRogers I am using django-debug-toolbar, it has SQL tab that shows total number of queries that were hit when page is loaded. It has only 2 queries(first query is ```select sysdatetime()``` probably to test the connection 2nd query is to bring the data). Attached image in query.